# Naming an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, debugging, anonymous-types

Is it possible to somehow set a name for anonymous functions?

There is no need to add function names to the namespace for anonymous functions but I would like to avoid seeing a large amount of (?) in my javascript debugger so I can keep the call stack trace informative.

Also can I safely pass normal declared functions as arguments instead of anonymous functions or will I walk into some strange errors. It seems to work.

```
$("object").bind("click", function() { alert("x"); });

$("object").bind("click", function debuggingName() { alert("x"); });
```

[Edit]

I meant something along the likes of

```
$("object").bind("click", function() { Function.Name = "debuggingName"; alert("x"); });
```

Comment: @Raynos - a named anonymous function is a contradiction in terms!!

Comment: Are you getting some error when you use your second construct above?

Comment: I just want to set something within an anonymous function that the debugger can pick up and display as a useful debugging function name. I want to use them exactly as I would use anonymous functions

Comment: @raynos: have you tried $("object").bind("click", function MY_NOT_SO_ANONYMOUS_FUNCTION_NAME () { alert("x"); });

Comment: @some how is that any different from the second example I have? Yes I have. it's probably the best way to handle it.

Comment: @Raynos: Sorry, I must have missed that you already wrote that. It's exactly the same as your second example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your second example is using a *named function expression*, which works fine in most browsers but has some problems in IE that you should be aware of before using it. I recommend reading [kangax's excellent article on this subject](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/).

Comment: Thank you, I was worried that passing a named function expression may cause errors.

Comment: Oh that's a lovely article. I didn't notice there was actaully a difference between named function expressions and function declaration.

Comment: Although actaully I believe my second example above is a function statement. Unles you count assigning the function declaration to arguments[1] as a named function expression. And I was starting to get a feeling that I understood javascript.

Comment: Your second example is definitely a named function expression. It looks identical to a function declaration except for the context: a function declaration isn't valid where an expression is expected (such as when passing a function parameter, as your example does). A function statement is another thing entirely: that's a Mozilla extension to ECMAScript to prevent a function declaration within, say, an `if` block from being a syntax error. kangax's article covers that too: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-statements

Comment: Oh bah I read the article wrong. Yes its a function expression. Out of curiosity does the phrase "named function expression" apply to such statements as var name = function thing() {} ? Or generally when are function expressions considered "named"

Comment: Yes, the right hand side of `var name = function thing() {}` is a named function expression. `var name = function() {}` is just a function expression. Distinguishing between named function expressions, function statements and function declarations is all based on context. If it's a place where the interpreter expects an expression (e.g. in a variable declaration) then it'll be a named function expression. If it's in global code or within a function (but not inside a block in either case), it's a function declaration. If it's within a block (e.g. an `if` block), it's a function statement.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this with arrow functions, it works for me on Node.

```
const createTask = ([name, type = 'default']) => {
  const fn = () => { ... }

  Object.defineProperty(fn, 'name', {
    value: name,
    configurable: true,
  })

  return fn
}
```

[MDN is somewhat misleading here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names)

> You cannot change the name of a function, this property is read-only...
>
> To change it, *you could use **Object.defineProperty()** though*.

[This answer provides more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431242/4842857)

Answer (score 1):

With ECMAScript2015 (ES2015, ES6) language specification, it is possible to do without the use of slow and unsafe *[eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)* function and without *[Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)* method which both corrupts function object and does not work in some crucial aspects anyway.

See, for example, this `nameAndSelfBind` function that is able to both name anonymous functions and renaming named functions, as well as binding their own bodies to themselves as *this* and storing references to processed functions to be used in an outer scope ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SSRRDD/zu7jf4ne/4/)):

```
(function()
{
  // an optional constant to store references to all named and bound functions:
  const arrayOfFormerlyAnonymousFunctions = [],
        removeEventListenerAfterDelay = 3000; // an auxiliary variable for setTimeout

  // this function both names argument function and makes it self-aware,
  // binding it to itself; useful e.g. for event listeners which then will be able
  // self-remove from within an anonymous functions they use as callbacks:
  function nameAndSelfBind(functionToNameAndSelfBind,
                           name = 'namedAndBoundFunction', // optional
                           outerScopeReference)            // optional
  {
    const functionAsObject = {
                                [name]()
                                {
                                  return binder(...arguments);
                                }
                             },
          namedAndBoundFunction = functionAsObject[name];

    // if no arbitrary-naming functionality is required, then the constants above are
    // not needed, and the following function should be just "var namedAndBoundFunction = ":
    var binder = function() 
    { 
      return functionToNameAndSelfBind.bind(namedAndBoundFunction, ...arguments)();
    }

    // this optional functionality allows to assign the function to a outer scope variable
    // if can not be done otherwise; useful for example for the ability to remove event
    // listeners from the outer scope:
    if (typeof outerScopeReference !== 'undefined')
    {
      if (outerScopeReference instanceof Array)
      {
        outerScopeReference.push(namedAndBoundFunction);
      }
      else
      {
        outerScopeReference = namedAndBoundFunction;
      }
    }
    return namedAndBoundFunction;
  }

  // removeEventListener callback can not remove the listener if the callback is an anonymous
  // function, but thanks to the nameAndSelfBind function it is now possible; this listener
  // removes itself right after the first time being triggered:
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", nameAndSelfBind(function(e)
  {
    e.target.removeEventListener('visibilitychange', this, false);
    console.log('\nEvent listener 1 triggered:', e, '\nthis: ', this,
                '\n\nremoveEventListener 1 was called; if "this" value was correct, "'
                + e.type + '"" event will not listened to any more');
  }, undefined, arrayOfFormerlyAnonymousFunctions), false);

  // to prove that deanonymized functions -- even when they have the same 'namedAndBoundFunction'
  // name -- belong to different scopes and hence removing one does not mean removing another,
  // a different event listener is added:
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", nameAndSelfBind(function(e)
  {
    console.log('\nEvent listener 2 triggered:', e, '\nthis: ', this);
  }, undefined, arrayOfFormerlyAnonymousFunctions), false);

  // to check that arrayOfFormerlyAnonymousFunctions constant does keep a valid reference to
  // formerly anonymous callback function of one of the event listeners, an attempt to remove
  // it is made:
  setTimeout(function(delay)
  {
    document.removeEventListener('visibilitychange',
             arrayOfFormerlyAnonymousFunctions[arrayOfFormerlyAnonymousFunctions.length - 1],
             false);
    console.log('\nAfter ' + delay + 'ms, an event listener 2 was removed;  if reference in '
                + 'arrayOfFormerlyAnonymousFunctions value was correct, the event will not '
                + 'be listened to any more', arrayOfFormerlyAnonymousFunctions);
  }, removeEventListenerAfterDelay, removeEventListenerAfterDelay);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally do:
    $("object").bind("click"
      , function name() { 
          alert("x"); 
    });

and don't run into any problems.

Doing so is encouraged in some of the major libraries:

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/firebug/MgnlqZ1bzX8

http://blog.getfirebug.com/2011/04/28/naming-anonymous-javascript-functions/

Answer (score -2):

If **dynamic** function name is the issue. You can try this:

```
function renameFunction(name, fn) {
    return (new Function("return function (call) { return function " + name +
       " () { return call(this, arguments) }; };")())(Function.apply.bind(fn));
} 

renameFunction('dynamicName',function() { debugger })();
```

source: [Nate Ferrero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871040/how-to-dynamically-set-a-function-object-name-in-javascript-as-it-is-displayed-i)

Comment: I've just seen a better solution for that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871040/how-to-dynamically-set-a-function-object-name-in-javascript-as-it-is-displayed-i

Comment: Don't ever do this. It's foolish and verbose.

Answer (score -3):

An anonymous function is a function without a name, it is executed from where it is defined. Alternatively, you can define the debugging function before using it.

```
function debuggingName() { 
    alert("x"); 
}

$("object").bind("click", debuggingName);
```