# Variable as eventListener named function expression name

Tags: javascript, variables, event-listener

I'm writing an awesome IIFE and want this to be as easy as possible for my users who use it. So I was thinking since some of them don't know that to easily remove an eventlistener without it already being a function we can give that inline function a name

**Example**

```
document.addEventListener('click',function dood(){
    //some function
},false);
document.removeEventListener('click',dood,false);
//instead of 
function dood(){
  //some function
} 
document.addEventListener('click',dood,false);
document.removeEventListener('click',dood,false);
```

But since they shouldn't know the name exactly I was wondering if we could do

```
var k = "name_of_function";
document.addEventListener('click',function window[k](){
  //the function
},false);
```

Though I know this does not work is there a way to do this? I'd like to make it so they can easily do this

```
object.cancel('name_of_function') //which will be the name of the instance
// they created earlier if they gave that instance a name
object={
  cancel:function(nm){
    document.removeEventListener(self.trigger,window[nm],false);
    //self.trigger really is this.trigger which they assign as either scroll,click,mousemove,etc.
  }
};
```

Any ideas? Or is this not possible at all?

usage is:

```
scrollex('element',{
    max:500,
    min:500,
    pin:200,
    offset:0.5,
    name:'google',//this then would be used in multiple instances
});

scrollex.events //shows all events and their names
scrollex.listen('google'); //it'll console log all info for this event
scrollex.cancel('google');
```

Comment: If you give an inline function a name, you've got a [nfe](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/), but the name still doesn't become a global identifier. Stick with your old solution.

Comment: I have no old solution I know that is an NFE but my API is wrapped in an IIFE I don't know why I stated it has nothing to do what I am looking for lol. if you mean the removeEventListener with an NFE then well that would be an annoyance to my users. I need it to be easiest as possible you know>

Comment: How are your users supposed to use your API anyway? What do they need to do with it? Maybe show the IEFE you already have.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track. But you should not use `window`, and some local object instead. And dynamically naming function expressions (or whatever that `function window[k](){}` was supposed to mean) is <s>impossible</s> [a pain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9479046/1048572) - don't try this. Just let them stay anonymous, and reference them only via property names / variables.

```
var object = (function() {
    var listeners = {
        name_of_function: function dood(){…}
    };
    document.addEventListener('click', listeners.name_of_function, false);

    return {
        cancel: function(nm) {
            document.removeEventListener('click', listeners[nm], false);
        }
    };
}());

// now, you can
object.cancel('name_of_function')
```

Comment: what if there are hundreds of custom functions? The users sets these properties and these properties are used inside the listener making it a custom function eachtime.

Comment: Well, you could easily have a hundred different functions with different property names in that `listeners` object. But maybe I misunderstood what you need.