# Why when I create an object the console says that its prototype is Object when it is Object.prototype in JS?

Tags: javascript, prototype

[image]

Why it says that it's `[[Prototype]]` is `Object`? `Object` is a `Function` object and the real prototype of `obj` is `Object.prototype`.

Comment: "Object is a Function object "  How do you figure?

Comment: Because `Object` is a constructor function. It's a function, and all function are `Function` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that its [[prototype]] (which you know is `Object.prototye`) "*is an `Object`*". No more no less. It does not imply that the value is the same as the global `Object` variable.

Comment: So you are implying that it only says that it's prototype is a regular object? Why is this relevant then, when every object's `[[Prototype]]` is an object? It can't be anything else.

Comment: It's not relevant, it's just how all objects are shown - there is no exception for `Object.prototype`. And actually, it does show the class name for custom instances (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25141170/1048572) for eample).