# Difference between ES6 object method assignment: a, 'a', and ['a']?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

With ES6, I can create a new object with functions like the following:

```
var obj = {
    something() {}
};
```

That makes sense. But I can also do this:

```
var obj = {
    'something'() {}
};
```

Or I can do this:

```
var obj = {
    ['something']() {}
};
```

Is there a difference between these three syntaxes? Why are all of these syntactically valid?

Comment: wow. I didn't know you could `['x']` within a literal.

Comment: Really curious if there would ever be any benefit to using the last one.

Comment: @Chris: Yes: you can do  `[Math.random()]`

Comment: @Chris: The benefit is that you could write a property with a name like ['1.2e+35'] =  7

Comment: @TalAvissar you can do that without square brackets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a difference between these three syntaxes?

Not wrt to the results in your example.

However, the different syntaxes do have different characteristics. The way the property name is defined is not specific to method definitions btw, the rules apply to all property names:

- Property names that are valid *identifier names* or number literals don't need to be quoted:

  ```
  {
    foo: ...,
    10e4: ...,
    if: ...,
  }
  ```
- Anything else needs to be quoted:

  ```
  {
    'foo+bar': ...,
    'abc def': ...,
    '123,45': ...,
  }
  ```
- The square bracket syntax is new in ES6 and allows you do dynamically compute property names:

  ```
  {
     [getPropertyName()]: ...,
     ['item' + (i * 3)]: ...,
  }
  ```

---

> Why are all of these syntactically valid?

Because the [grammar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer) allows it:

```
MethodDefinition :
    PropertyName ( StrictFormalParameters ) { FunctionBody }
    GeneratorMethod
    get PropertyName ( ) { FunctionBody }
    set PropertyName( PropertySetParameterList ) { FunctionBody }

PropertyName :
    LiteralPropertyName
    ComputedPropertyName

LiteralPropertyName :
    IdentifierName
    StringLiteral
    NumericLiteral

ComputedPropertyName :
    [ AssignmentExpression ]
```

(not sure what kind of answer you expect here)

If you consider methods to be equivalent to assigning a function to the property, it seems to make sense to apply the same rules for property names to function/method names.

Comment: As it turns out, you can do `['foo' + someFunction()]` with brackets and have dynamic (on-creation) property names. Neat trick.

Comment: "*except for the function names*" - shouldn't even these be the same?

Comment: @Bergi: I meant what georg was pointing out in his answer. The last one doesn't set the name of the function. I should clarify that.

Comment: @FelixKling: Actually it does? [Pretty useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9479081/1048572) even

Comment: @Bergi: I see now. (the demo doesn't seem to work in latest Chrome though :-/)

Answer (score 2):

First and second are the same, and do the same as

```
obj.something = function something() {}
```

the third one creates an anonymous function and stores it in obj.something. It's an equivalent to this:

```
obj['something'] = function() {}
```

Quotes allow to create keys (and hence function names) that are not valid identifiers in JS, for example:

```
 var obj = {
    '123'() {}
};
```

creates a function with the name `123`, believe it or not.

The square brackets syntax allows arbitrary expressions, so you can do

```
 var obj = {
   ['myfunc_' + getFuncName()] () {}
 }
```

and similar cool things.

Comment: *"...and do the same as..."* Except that `something` isn't bound inside the function.

Comment: @zerkms: Yes: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-method-definitions-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation (step 3)

Comment: FWIW,  `var obj = { 123() {} };` is valid too.

Comment: @FelixKling: thanks for the link, what I don't understand it why `[...]()` doesn't do SetFunctionName. The standard doesn't seem to care if a PropertyName is Literal or Computed.

Comment: For a computed property name, the [`PropName` procedure](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer-static-semantics-propname) returns "emtpy", i.e. the name cannot be set to anything.

Comment: @FelixKling: ah, makes sense (well, it doesn't actually, but that's ECMA for you...)

Comment: @FelixKling: `PropName` doesn't matter for `SetFunctionName`. It's only used statically to prevent duplicate `constructor`s, static `prototype` properties and similar in classes.