# Replace arguments.callee inside of new Function

Tags: javascript, function, self-reference

Some string is converted into function by `new Function(...)` call.

How can I get referent to this function inside of the string without using `arguments.callee`?

```
var f = new Function('return arguments.callee.smth');
f.smth = 128;
f(); // 128
```

Comment: You cannot. Why would you need to do this (What are you using the `Function` constructor for)? Please provide your actual code so that we can suggest a solution appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24032179/1048572) for passing values into the constructed function's scope.

Comment: @Bergi, actually I want to [extend function](//stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/4928642), but idea about getting self-reference by the generated function by itself seems interesting for me.

Comment: Should you delete this question, or should we answer that it's impossible?

Comment: @Bergi, answered it. But the answer is useless for question about class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do such thing is to use closure.

For example:

```
var f = (function () {
  var f = new Function('return this().smth').bind(function () { return f });
  return f;
})();

f.smth = 128;
f();
```

Or so:

```
var f = (function (g) {
  return function f() {
    return g.apply(f, arguments)
  };
})(new Function('return this.smth'));

f.smth = 128;
f();
```

Anyway, seems like `arguments.callee` works inside constructed function regardless strict mode.

Additional links about the topic:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

  > A use of arguments.callee with no good alternative
  >
  > However, in a case like the following, there are not alternatives to `arguments.callee`, so its deprecation could be a bug (see bug [725398](//bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=725398))
- https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263

Comment: That doesn't return the `new Function()`, but a "bound function" (which e.g. doesn't have a `.prototype`). You could have gotten that easier :-)

Comment: @Bergi, _"You could have gotten that easier :-)"_ - how?

Comment: By scrapping `new Function` and just returning a closure (created from a function expression), I mean.