# Can you use template literal for function name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**can you use template literals to name functions dynamically**

```
let variable = "something"

function `constant${variable}` () {
               //do something
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected template string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any non-eval way to create a function with a runtime-determined name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479046/is-there-any-non-eval-way-to-create-a-function-with-a-runtime-determined-name)

Comment: I know, but is there a hack way to do this somehow?

Comment: @Ivar. That is how to call it. OP wants to create it.

Comment: What is this for? What are you trying to build. With this approach you first need a hack to create the function and then you'll need another hack to use it. I'm almost certain that there's a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable and fetch its context using `this` keyword to declare your function

Example

```
let fnName = "CoolDynamicFunction";

this[`${fnName}`] = () => { 
  console.log("I'm a cool dynamic function") 
}
```

and then call it using

```
CoolDynamicFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to achieve is below your original code shouldnt work because you are trying to put string where variable name expected.

PS. By using this instead of window or global you can use snippet in both browser and node.js

```js
let variable = "something"

this[ `constant${variable}`]= ()=> {
               console.log("it works");
}
constantsomething()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below, we can use `window` or `separate object` to create a dynamic function using template literal

```
let variable = "something"

    window[`constant${variable}`] = function  () {
         console.log('dynamic func')
    }
```

(or)

```
let variable = "something"

var obj = {
    [`constant${variable}`]: function  () {
         console.log('dynamic func')
    }
}


obj.constantsomething()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not like that, because a template literal evaluates to a string, and you can't write **`function "abc"() { ... }`** either.

However, you can try putting it in **global context** using the name + bracket notation. E.g. when running in a browser:

```js
let variable = "something"

window[`constant${variable}`] = function() {
  console.log("Hello!");
}

constantsomething();
```

And with a *Node* project, it will probably go something like this:

```
let variable = "something"

global[`constant${variable}`] = function() {
  console.log("Hello!");
}

constantsomething();
```