# How I could use template literals in javascript in a variable name?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, javascript-objects, template-literals

I want to declare a variable name via template literals
How it is possible ?

```js
let z = 3;

let test`${z}` = "hello"; //or = new obj() for example

console.log(test3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

It is not possible. Template literals are used for `strings` only.

It is same as: `var 'string_var' = 'myval'`  // Not accepted.

But, you can do it for object properties.

Such as:

```js
let z = 3;

let obj = {}
obj[`test${z}`] = "hello"

console.log(obj.test3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible. This is my code, referencing:
[Can you use template literal for function name in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278953/can-you-use-template-literal-for-function-name-in-javascript)

```html
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  global[`list_${i}`] = require(`./LP_${i}_Top_Holder.json`);
}
```