# Set the name of a function at runtime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set the name of a function at runtime in JavaScript?

```
var ctor = function() {}; // Anonymous function because I don't know the name ahead of runtime.
ctor.name = 'foo'; // Pseudocode  - this is effectively what I want to do
```

I want the above to be equivalent to:

```
var ctor = function foo() {};
```

**Edit**

Here is an example use-case:

```
function mix(fn1, fn2, name) {    
    var ctor = function() {};
    ctor.name = name; // Vain attempt to set the name of the function.
    ctor.prototype = Object.create(fn1.prototype);

    Object.keys(fn2.prototype).map(function(k) {
        ctor.prototype[k] = fn2.prototype[k];
    });

    // Return a constructor function with the prototype configured.
    return ctor;
}

function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.foo = function(){};

function Bar(){}
Bar.prototype.bar = function() {};

var Foobar = mix(Foo, Bar, 'Foobar');
console.log(new Foobar()); // ctor {bar: function, foo: function} (in Chrome) - I wanted Foobar { bar: function, foo: function }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `eval`?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871040/how-to-dynamically-set-a-function-object-name-in-javascript-as-it-is-displayed-i

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (Not hypothetical -- this could influence the nature of the answer.)

Comment: @apsillers I was considering the case whereby a constructor function is created at runtime, and I wanted the resulting function to have sensible metadata behind the scenes so that debuging, logging etc is more meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` was a non-standard only supported by some browsers.

Now, it has been standardized in ECMAScript 6:

> [**19.2.4.2 name**](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-name)
>
> The value of the `name` property is an String that is descriptive of the
>   function. The name has no semantic significance but is typically a
>   variable or property name that is used to refer to the function at its
>   point of definition in ECMAScript code. This property has the
>   attributes { [[Writable]]: **false**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**,
>   [[Configurable]]: **true** }.
>
> Anonymous functions objects that do not have a contextual name
>   associated with them by this specification do not have a `name` own
>   property but inherit the `name` property of %FunctionPrototype%.

Therefore, your code will work on browsers that don't support `name`, but the new property will be writable and enumerable. And on browsers that support it, your code won't work because `name` is not writable.

Therefore, a better equivalent code would be

```js
Object.defineProperty(ctor, 'name', {
    value: 'foo',
    configurable: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: **This may be upsetting for some people who like their code to be safe and predictable.**

*Of course, you won't actually do this, because you're sensible, right?*

```
function rename(fn, name) {
  var fnStr = fn.toString().replace(/function/, 'function ' + name);
  eval.call(window, fnStr);
  return window[name];
}

var tmp = function(a, b) { return a + b; };
rename(tmp, 'add');
add(3, 4); // 7
```

Of course, depending on how well behaved you need to be *(not very if you use eval)*, you could *(but you won't)* go one step further.

```
Function.prototype.rename = function(name) {
  return rename(this, name);
};
```

Do this in actual code and people will hate you, *but that's ok, because you won't*.

There are a few hiccups (and probably some broken edge cases) to do with the scope in which the function was defined. Eval uses the context of this to decide which scope to operate within, so passing the window object means the renamed function will always be defined within the window object.

Fairly contrived example, but it should give you some idea of the pitfalls.

```
function init() {
  function go() {
    return 'go';
  };

  var ctor = function() {
    return 'ctor';
  };

  rename(ctor, 'go');
  go(); // 'go'

  next();  
}

function next() {
  go(); // 'ctor'
}
```