# How to change Javascript function name that appears in toString()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

`Function.name` property is configurable and can be overriden, but if I try

```js
function foo() {}
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'name', {value: 'bar'})
```

`foo.toString()` still shows up as `"function foo() {}"` but I expected it to be `"function bar() {}"`.

Comment: You cannot update the "name" property of a function object.

Comment: Why would you want to change the output of `.toString()`?

Comment: @Pointy - You can't update it (assign to it), but as the OP said, you *can* redefine it with `defineProperty`. But that doesn't change the string returned by `Function.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder really? MDN describes it as "read-only", but that's MDN

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871040/3001761, but you'll have to read beyond the first answer.

Comment: @Pointy - You can redefine read-only properties as long as they're configurable. `name` is configurable.

Comment: Yep I just tried in the console. I'm too lazy to edit MDN however.

Comment: @Pointy - [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) looks right to me...? (Not nit-picking; just curious. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well its *correct*, but using the term "read-only" in the fairly casual opening paragraph(s) seems like something that could be clarified. It has of course never occurred to me to update the "name" property of a function, but I've always assumed it was not modifiable and I'm pretty sure that assumption has played a role in one or more old answers to questions here.

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah, the whole thing could use a bit of a style update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this 100% reliably. That's because of the definition of [`Function.prototype.toString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring), which uses the [[SourceText]] internal slot, which is set as the function is being created from the source code that was used to create the function. It doesn't use the `name` property.

You could try to override `toString` on the function as well, but of course that would still fail if someone explicitly used `Function.prototype.toString` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to cheat with something like `toString`, maybe you can consider using `Proxy`.

Example:

```js
const YouWannaChangeName = "modified";

function x(a, b, c) {
    return 0;
}

console.log(x.toString());

x = new Proxy(x, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        if ([Symbol.toPrimitive, "toString"].includes(prop)) {
            return function () {
                const re = new RegExp(`^function ${target.name}`);
                return target.toString().replace(re, `function ${YouWannaChangeName}`);
            };
        } else {
            return target[prop];
        }
    }
});

console.log(x.toString());
console.log("" + x);
```

This is also valid for native functions.

**Note:** Until 2022, the browser environment doesn't provide any `Proxy` aware API. In fact, the spec also explicitly states that `Proxy` shouldn't be detected. So I think this method is reliable.

- If you plan to deploy on server side like Node.js, or privileged environment such as browser extension, it'll be able to be detected.
- If the target function is custom function, make sure it's dosen't have `configurable: false` and `writable: false`)