# JavaScript Symbol type: (non-string object keys)

Tags: javascript, string, object, key, ecmascript-6

What is the "Symbol" javascript type [as mentioned in this ECMAScript 6 draft specification](http://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-8.1.6)?

To quote the spec:

> The Symbol type is the set of all non-String values that may be used as the key of an Object property.
>
> Each possible Symbol values is unique and immutable.
>
> Symbol values have a single observable attribute called [[Private]] whose immutable value is either true or false. A private symbol is a Symbol value whose [[Private]] attribute has the value true.

I thought object keys were strings only, and I'm not alone. To quote [this accepted SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067160/552067):

> …object keys are always strings…

Could you explain what the symbol type is, and demonstrate its usage. I'm trying to make sense of the spec.

Thanks!

Comment: That's ES6 spec, not sure but see if this helps: https://github.com/dherman/tc39-codex-wiki/blob/master/data/es6/symbols/index.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought object keys were strings only

You're right, but that was true for EcmaScript 5 only. ES 6 / harmony is a draft for something new!

> I'm trying to make sense of the spec

It's a draft only, [rapidly changing](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts). How symbols are used and whether or how they can be created by arbitrary scripts does not seem to have settled yet (scan through the [versions](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts&s=symbol#older_drafts) for changes).

If you scroll down to the very end of [that document](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html) (even below Annex F), you for example will see a *Section 8.4.4: Symbol Exotic Objects* that has been moved out there. It states

> Exotic Symbol objects provide alternative definitions for all of the essential internal methods.

You can see them used at [section 8.1.7.4 *Well-Known Symbols and Intrinsics*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-8.1.7.4) for example. For proposed uses (and still existing problems / open questions) of `Symbol` constructors have a look at [these](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3aproxy_symbol_decoupled) [strawman](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3aprivate_names) pages or [this wiki site](https://github.com/dherman/tc39-codex-wiki/blob/master/data/es6/symbols/index.md).

Answer (score 0):

`Symbol` is a new addition to the language proposed as part of [ECMAScript 6](http://ecma-international.org/memento/TC39-M.htm):

> Current work on ECMAScript™
>
> Work on future ECMAScript™ editions continues as part of the previously announced ECMAScript™ "Harmony" project. More details of the current work on ECMAScript "Harmony" are described on this Wiki. A sixth edition of the standard is currently under development with a target date of December 2013 for completion.

Comment: See section [8.1.7.4](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-8.1.7.4) for the built-in symbols

Answer (score 0):

We use symbols to make the properties or methods of an object private. So we hide the details and show only the essentials. It is called `abstraction`.

How to implement this: Let's create a simple class with "radius" property

```
class Circle {
    constructor(radius) {
        this.radius = radius; 
    }}
```

A symbol is essentially a unique identifier. Every time we call this function we get a unique identifier. It is not a constructor function,though.

```
Symbol()===Symbol() //will be false
```

Implementation:

```
const _radius=Symbol()
class Circle {
    constructor(radius) {
    this[_radius] = radius; //since property name starts with _, we use bracket notation
        }
         }
```

now test this. Create an instance of Circle:

```
const c=new Circle;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c))// you will see a number on the console.
```