# Javascript place object in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is it possible to store an Object into an Object..I have tried to this in my code with entry:entry but no success.

I have no problem with Object[String, String] but Object[Object, String] is not working for me.

```
$.each(data.scheduleEntries, function(index, entry){
  arr[{entry:entry}] = entry.startDate;
})
```

Comment: `arr[{entry:entry}] = entry.startDate;` Uh? Why are you using an object literal as an index?

Comment: An object always requires a `key:str -> value:any` syntax, you cant just do `{key: object, string}` Also, try to use english for all code. I know `teller` is dutch for counter but it's best practise to keep using english everywhere ;)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings . Tl;dr: keys in javascript objects can be strings and strings only.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use objects as keys in objects. Property names always are strings. You can use objects as property values of course.

In your case, using `arr[entry]` directly should work; if you really need objects as keys you will be able to use [`Map` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with ES6 (there also exist less efficient shims).