# How to avoid unwanted key cast from number to string in Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, immutable.js

I'm trying to use Immutable in a project with reactjs and flux.

Let's say I have a .js file with the code

```
console.log ( Immutable.Map({1: 2}).toString() )
```

I browserify this script and run it from the browser (Google Chrome), the
result is:

```
"Map { "1": 2 }"
```

notice that the key, 1, is now a string, not a number.

If I try the same code directly in the console of the site http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ I get the correct result:

```
"Map { 1: 2 }"
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to get the correct result (key as number) in my script?

I'm using node v0.10.26, Browserify 5.12.0 and immutable 3.7.1

Comment: I think objects keys are always string, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings)

Answer (score 6):

Giving Map an array of key value pairs seems to do the trick:

```
> Immutable.Map([[1, 2]]).toString()
'Map { 1: 2 }'
```

see https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/Map for more info