# Using a function as an Object's key

Tags: javascript

I have a function that accepts a function parameter that I'd like to use as the key to an object...

```
function foo(func) {
    return { func: true };
}
```

This, of course, returns an object with the string 'func' as the key (not what I want).

Is the right solution to create a string from `func` and then create the object?

Is there a way to create a hash from a function?

Comment: What functionality do you want to achieve? / That you can not when using the functions _name_ as the key...?

Comment: The keys in a object are always strings or numbers. Here you can read more :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind that [object keys are always strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings) you should be able to use this syntax:

```
result = {};
result[func] = true;
return result;
```

Comment: @sfletche sure. But beware: keys are always strings. And even though other types may appear to work at a first glance, they might bite you with awkward bugs in future.

Answer (score 1):

Though you can use functions as keys directly, you can use a hash code function to get the string representation of the function to create integer keys.  I got one from http://erlycoder.com/49/javascript-hash-functions-to-convert-string-into-integer-hash-.

```
function hashFunc(func){
    var str = func.toString();

    var hash = 0;
    if (str.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
        hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    console.log(hash);
    return hash;
}

var col = {}

function add(func) {
    col[hashFunc(func)] = true;
}

function get(func) {
    return col[hashFunc(func)] || false;
}

// test
add(hashFunc);
console.log(get(add)); // false
console.log(get(hashFunc)); // true
```