# Why {["abc"]:123} exists?

Tags: javascript

I know there's no "dictionary" in Javascript. So the key can be *"more than a string"* . But how to explain the result `"[index] = index"`?

```
a={["abc"]:123}
a["abc"]==123
true
```

Why it works?

I've update the statement above. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Your code does not work. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't do that. What version of ES are we talking about anyway? This will result in a SyntaxError.

Comment: @Xatenev I think OP is trying to say that if you have `obj = {"abc":123}`, you can access `obj[["abc"]]` (note extra brackets) and it "works". That's indeed because the array gets converted to a string.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That would make sense. Thanks for explaining. I thought OP tried to execute his **exact** JS code here and it worked.

Comment: Your code does not work: See this fiddle: https://codepen.io/HPawelyn/pen/BZBoVa?editors=1111

Comment: I don't think hemeant that as an assignment, he means that the two syntaxes are equivalent.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks for explaining for me.

Comment: I'm trying to explain that {["abc"]:123} result in a object "looks like the same with" {"abc":123} . Sorry for my poor statement @Barmar

Comment: @fxp I understood it, H.Pauwelyn didn't.

Comment: Why do you think the key can be more than a string?

Comment: @Barmar at least number can be key as well

Comment: @fxp The number gets converted to a string. Try `Object.keys([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: try this a[1e2] =23; a['1e2'] @Barmar

Comment: `1e2` is `100`, so the first is `a['100'] = 23`

Comment: @Barmar You are right. And the Object.keys(a) is also ["100"]. So you mean that the key can be only string? I find another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings which says a[1] is actually converted to a["1"]. And I find another reference about Symbol https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols that means key can be Symbol for now?

Answer (score 6):

In new es6 you can use this `[]` to compute dynamic keys.

```js
var a = {
  [2 * 3]: "what"
}
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ES6 [Computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax:

```
{ [expression]: value }
```

In your case `expression` is just a string `"abc"`.