# Accessing indexable object in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a following `indexable object` declared which will contain list of `Video` Models identified by some `key` which is a `number`.

component.ts

```
private videoItems : {[key: number]: Array<Video>};      // indexable object

constructor(private action: Action, private videoModel: Video) {}
```

And I have assigned it in the following way in component

```
this.action.items.forEach(
            (item : Video) => {
                this.videoItems[item.idVideo] = Object.assign(new Video(),this.videoModel);
            }
        );
```

Video.model.ts

```
export class Video {

    private _idVideo : number;

    get idVideo (): number {
        return this._idVideo ;
    }

    set idVideo (value: number) {
        this._idVideo = value;
    }
}
```

If I try to access the `videoItems` like `this.videoItems[12]`, I get `undefined`. Where as I if I access it like `this.videoItems['12']` I get the `video` object properly. My question is even though I have declared the key as `number` and is also set with a `number`, then why should I access it using a `string`?

Comment: that's not a typed array, it's an indexable object. it behaves like an object. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys for JavaScript objects must be [strings or symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings). The latter is a recent addition. Numbers are coerced to strings, so code like this works:

```
let x = {}
x[10] = 'foo';
console.log(x[10]); // Prints "foo"
console.log(x['10']); // Prints "foo"
x['20'] = 'bar';
console.log(x[20]); // Prints "bar"
```

Try it out in the browser or node and see that it *does* indeed behave that way. It's quite strange that it does not in your case. Perhaps there's something else going on?