# How to extend the Record type's keys in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is this intended behavior in typescript?

```js
const NeedsRecord = <T extends Record<string, any>>(record: T) => {}

NeedsRecord({
    5: " Should error, doesn't "
});
```

I would like to constrain the types of the `Record`'s key type by inheritance. How can I do this?

Having the key type as the generic parameter instead also doesn't work as expected:

```js
const NeedsRecord = <T extends string>(record: Record<T, any>) => { }

NeedsRecord({
    5: " Should error, doesn't "
});
```

Explicitly defining the union key type works, but is ugly to use:

```js
const NeedsRecord = <T extends string>(record: Record<T, any>) => { }

NeedsRecord<"a"|"b">({
    a: "works",
    b: "works",
    // 5: " fails properly"
    // c: " fails properly"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended TypeScript behavior. "Numeric" object keys are [actually strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46043752/2887218), and TypeScript treats string index signatures as [supporting number and even symbol keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types) for this reason.

If you want to force the compiler to produce errors when you pass a `number`-valued key, you can do it like this:

```
const needsRecord = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: K extends number ? never : any }>(
  record: T
) => { }

needsRecord({
  a: "works",
  b: "works",
  5: "error" // string is not assignable to never
});
```

But beware... in JavaScript there is really no difference between `{5: ""}` and `{"5": ""}`, because keys get coerced to strings:

```
const oN = { 5: "" };
console.log(typeof (Object.keys(oN)[0])); // "string"
const oS = { "5": "" };
console.log(JSON.stringify(oS) === JSON.stringify(oN)); // true
```

And that means the above `needsRecord()` will think this is fine:

```
needsRecord({
  a: "works",
  b: "works",
  "5": "oops" // no error
})
```

but there's no great reason to allow one and disallow the other.  And TypeScript doesn't currently have a great built-in way to exclude "numeric-like strings", so I'm not sure there's much more you can do here.

Given that `5` and `"5"` as keys are the same, why do you actually care about prohibiting this?  Is it possible that TypeScript's intended behavior is actually acceptable for your use case?  Or does something actually go wrong if you allow numeric keys?

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCm8AmEBK9QCckwLwwB4AVGeADynjBRgG8YBtAaRgEswYBreATxADMYRALoAuGC3KVqEOAFcAtgCN4mGAH448AG6qY4gIZgeMAL4A+ABQAoGDEwYQ2cUWsBKPObpnr1hMjRHbEtaWxgDcQAiAHcnTghIgBowpSjYzHiksIBWKNVMJ0iYAHpimGhMdgBzNlkwEFgDCAhWKrADJQAbeBgoEC1dTGtTNwBuWz9EFHQsJBCwiJgYuITku1Sl9My1pezIqJAQAAcEkrL60kwCoZHfUEhYEAA5PG9cpaLTcfuIEG6AOk6ICqligPCO8AEMEsAHklAArDBQf7cHgQSzPNwMAAMwjcYzOSwq1Ui1h+jwAyq96JE9lFPt9wL8AUCQQApCkwp7-YlgKqsfg8DEUjy4MUwDlcnlQSp8gVCzEE0q9TByeC+IA)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With your info I realized that I could expand my use case to allow for string/number/symbol unions rather than trying to restrict keys to strings only.