# How to implement a "GetTypeByPath" type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

My requirement is that the type alias can be passed in two parameters, the first one is the object type, the second one is a dot expression that indicates the path of the field.

For example:

```
type Obj = {
  a: {
    b: string[]
  }
  c: number[]
}

GetTypeByPath<Obj, 'a.b'>  // => string[]
GetTypeByPath<Obj, 'c.5'>  // => number
```

So how the `GetTypeByPath` type would be look like?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nlgz5w) work for your use cases?  If not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz Wow..!!! That looks perfect! Thanks man! Could you leave some comment for me? because that looks too magical to me..!

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance; please check against your use cases first, though… these sort of “deep indexing” operations tend to have weird edge cases and different people want to see different things happen.  I hate to spend too much time on an answer and then have to change the whole thing because of a missed use case.

Comment: @jcalz I've test your solution in my usecase, and that just works perfectly. I really appreciate it! I'm wondering how the 'Idx' is actually work, and what does 'Idx' stands for?

Comment: I refactored my `Idx` type (which stands for "Index", btw) to something easier to explain which serves the same purpose (but please check it again!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered [this sort of "deep indexing" question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64575901/2887218) before, but it seems like there are always slightly different use cases.  The basic approach is to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to split the path string at dot characters `"."` and use a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) to walk down through the nested properties.  I'll refer to your `GetTypeByPath<T, K>` as `DeepIndex<T, K>` to be consistent with prior instances of this question.

Anyway, the implementation looks something like:

```
type DeepIndex<T, K extends string> = T extends object ? (
  K extends `${infer F}.${infer R}` ? DeepIndex<Idx<T, F>, R> : Idx<T, K>
) : never;
```

where `Idx<T, K>` represents the "shallow" [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) operation normally written as just `T[K]`.  We'll come to how to implement `Idx<T, K>` (and why we don't just write `T[K]`) in a bit.

For now, let's just convince ourselves that `DeepIndex<T, K>` does what we expect.  First, we won't try indexing into primitives, so the whole thing is wrapped in `T extends object ? ( ... ) : never`.  We *could* index into primitives, but then we'd be supporting things like `DeepIndex<Obj, 'a.b.5.length.toPrecision'>` evaluating to `(precision?: number | undefined) => string`.  If you remove that wrapper then that's what you'd get.

The heart of the type is just: try to split the path at the first dot into the first part of the string `F` and the rest of the string `R`.  If you can do that, then you want to `DeepIndex` into the `T[F]` property at the path `R`.  If you can't, then there are no more dots and we'll just treat the path `K` as a single key and return `T[K]`.

---

So how do we implement `Idx<T, K>`?  One fairly universal complication is that there's no simple way to express to the compiler that the path fragment at `K` will definitely be one of the keys of `T`. So one thing we'd need to do is check for that.  We can try it as:

```
type Idx<T, K extends string> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
```

And this kind of works:

```
type X = DeepIndex<Obj, 'a.b'>  // string[]
```

Until it doesn't:

```
type Y = DeepIndex<Obj, 'c.5'>  // never
```

---

And this is the place where your use case differs from others I've seen.  You are indexing into a `number[]` with the *string* value `"5"`.  But [the `Array<T>` type definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/78ef3e70c901bd5dfed061b659c4a330aafe44a3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1401) has a `number` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), and `"5"` is not a `number`.  It's a "numeric string", so you should be able to index into an array with it (since object keys in JavaScript are [actually strings and not really numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46043752/2887218)), but the compiler doesn't see `"5" extends keyof (number[])` as being true.

So we need to account for such numeric string keys.  Let's try this:

```
type Idx<T, K extends string> =
  K extends keyof T ? T[K] :
  K extends `${number}` ? number extends keyof T ? T[number] : never : never;
```

Here we're saying that if `K` is a string version of a number (the "pattern template literal" `` `${number}` `` syntax was introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)), and if the type `T` has a numeric index signature, then we should index into `T` with `number` instead of `K`.   Let's test it out again:

```
type X = DeepIndex<Obj, 'a.b'>  // string[] 
type Y = DeepIndex<Obj, 'c.5'>  // number
```

Looks good!

---

Of course there are tons of edge cases.  For those come come later, even if this meets the needs of the original person asking the question, there's no guarantee it will do what *you* expect... so you should really test against all your use cases.

For example: it's quite hard to check if `K` is a valid path before you do the indexing.  Instead of a compiler warning if you write `DeepIndex<Obj, "something.that.is.definitely.not.a.path">`, you'll just get [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) out, which may or may not be acceptable:

```
type Z = DeepIndex<Obj, 'oopsieDaisy'> // never
```

So test carefully!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A9jKSDeBYAUAUkgC4CeMyAkgCYAeAPACoA0SA0khHSRMDVigkATgEtgAcwB8SALwcuPPgKQBrCGTQAzJEyQB+XQG12AXSQAuJMAgA3CMIDcBIqQrIAIhAgwq-bsxsnNy8-IIi4tJyuoqhKmgARgBWEPAkBkgAFK7EwUphSAAGACTY4loOSABiAL4AdKXllQBKNYUZXj5+NAG0jKzVUmzNMlZ9gRxSrgCUltZ2Ds6E+MTklKjJ0XgrxEggVtu7uwlWQmKSRqY5SDXX8FbAAK5gCQ6XrrfLq+5IABrRnV8-kYKGSbAA5CA6glwTIkAB6eFIM6RS5IQC8G4BgPdca2QAE0Ad4gT0QWCkOD4HUAKyw4iI+b2YQYwCMey58J8CKBILAEMgqqI6Dg2d91uMBnk4uFzlFZNcJcosOpNDo9IYmCZzBY5bEFUVSk8Xg42hkDa8mSFdUrtDE1UZTQ5NQzKg8Fk5hW51oDugFxTqCijJDJ5HoLQVEik0hlsjtcn6VCUysAKkzag1E8mkK12oYvcCGGK2FUhpnRkgC5MZnMbIylq56bikAAJMBgQldPOgpIQqEJal1AA2fAkJAAFnUSGgAArCVKiKCiNDAWF1pEN5ut+SZGAz+BzhfAfQPZ5mpAAHyQj38WnEEBos1kMgDEndDc7W2u+yFMeOpwiFyu36fEc9zWMebwAcQHI7A2-zyLmJIMJ23bQrSCJIk+aJYjiPwEnBRLeqSXbkvAqH0vaTJYdBPwAFptsSARIeSaAYPOEAeCAc5kLSZGumyBBQQQQA)

Comment: Fantastic explanation!! Again, thank you so much!!  And, could you just wrap this code into "source code"? ---> `type Idx<T, K extends string> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : K extends ${number} ? number extends keyof T ? T[number] : never : never;`

Comment: Whoops, fixed. 