# Typescript error while trying to access an instance property or method via dynamic input and [] brackets

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
class Label{
  constructor(
    public name:string='name',
    public configPath:string='path',
    public foo:{bar:string} = {bar:'hello'}
  ){

  }
}

const labelName:string = 'bob'
const configPath:string = './path/to/a/config.file'
const label_name = new Label(labelName, configPath);

function line(line: string):void {
  const regex = /\./g;
  let path = line.split(regex);
  let startingObj = label_name;
  function addPath(path: string) {
    startingObj = startingObj[path];
  }
  path.forEach(addPath);
  console.log(startingObj);
}

line('name')
line('foo.bar')
```

line is an input that I want to use to log elements via a terminal request. I imagine it is pretty dangerous way to access the members of a class, it is something that I plan to use during development. `line` should have this *format*: `report.q1`, an I should be able to log the values in the console.

Ts is complaining about `startingObj = startingObj[path];` with this error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' >can't be used to index type 'Label'. No index signature with a parameter of >type 'string' was found on type 'App'.ts(7053)

I created a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyYCMCmIDeAoa1gHsB2EALgE4CuwhOxAFJltAA6kIgCWw0eYAtkgFxFirPAHMAvAHIuvCQBo6WJi3bZ8AM1YiACmEIALASWHiJDXXrkLGzNhzU4cfVAjDFDQ0QF9oY6M9d8EnooIDgSnnQAlBh0ERHouASE0ODIIAByPPyCxj7QEgg4CBIJ+ESqeBra5u65vhIAdAD0ZvpNlE1gTYlVDRogSCWJ5akoAPrSSHl4SADucIgo1KMZWbIVVTr6kQDc6OhqpHgUrPgpwkjLF3zQOaKRfABuOKwAJn50w8nESCJIAB55JoAHWaIj2WAGyVaejybBmDQgDDYhGoPz+-12dCht0IrkIxgA8ggAFZwxYgCZZCHQQ7HAlnMCvV5bPTUGE3O4iSIfei4-FE0l5IgC0TEkkAbRhAF0aRFFOY+lQAKJgYBspks8xYrDDHADBqhETUEXEAli0lY+Lwy5SLISSLoG3UCT2HANFzEB1AA) to explain what I am trying to do =).

What can I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Na2EEm) that's great, but please also put the full example in the body of the post as text.)

Comment: You are right I will provide that ..

Comment: shall I edit my original message? I think I will do that!

Comment: I know my first comment was a wall of text, but the operative part of it is that the [mre] should be **plain text in the body of your post**.

Comment: What you're doing isn't something the TypeScript compiler can verify as type safe.  Your `startingObject` *starts* as a `Label` but then becomes other types, and TS doesn't model or track *mutation* like this.  Splitting strings by dots also won't result in strongly typed string literals.  If you just want to suppress the error and move on, you can annotate `startingObject` as the `any` type to stop the compiler from caring much about what you do with it, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mxDjxm). Normally I wouldn't recommend using `any`, but in this case I don't think there's much better.

Comment: If you want I could write up an answer detailing this.  Otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Ehy, thank for the suggestion. In fact I think I set tsconfig to complain for `any` as well. Actually the object doesn't mutate, I just want to access those members. The fact is that there is no way for ts to know what I will put in the string. Maybe if I do some type of validation on the input this could help type script identify the type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245787/discussion-between-giacomo-gagliano-and-jcalz).

Comment: The original object doesn't mutate, but the contents of `startingObj` changes type from `Label` to some property value of `Label`, etc.  So either you need to represent `startingObject` as `any`, or as something like `Label | Label[keyof Label] | {[K in keyof Label]: Label[K][keyof Label[K]]][keyof Label] | ... ` to capture the fact that it can be any possible property or subproperty or subsubproperty etc of `Label`.  And even if you do that the compiler won't be happy letting you index into it because it won't know what's going on.

Comment: You could make a helper function to represent deep indexing like [this q/a shows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71096136/2887218), but the implementation is not guaranteed safe by the compiler; if you want to treat it like a black box then maybe it would meet your needs, but you're not even using the resulting deep indexed object outside the `line()` function, just `console.log`ging it, so it seems perverse to force the compiler to represent the complicated "deep index" type operation only to throw the information away.

Comment: There really won't be anything better than `any`.  If you have something (it isn't tsconfig, maybe eslint) set to warn on any instance of `any` you can work around it with `unknown`s and `never`s and other things, but none of those will give you type safety, so I'd say the linter rule should not be enforced for such a situation.  Unless I get more information from an updated example, I don't have anything better to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking further into Typescript documentations I realized why it is giving that problem, and I found a solution by doing ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyYCMCmJoG8BQ1rAPYDsIAXAJwFdgjcSAKLbaABzIRAEthp8wBbJALmjESbfAHNoAXmgBybnxkAaetmasOOAgDM2YgApgiAC0HDRE6TMaGjSlUxbtOW3LkFpoCMCVOlz0AF8pdE9vQRkjFBBcGUD6AEp0egCMFIw8QiJocGQQADleASE-cWCZBFwEGXSCYk18HX0bXxFSywA6AHprY06qTrBOjMb2nRAkaoy6nJQAfXkkYPwkAHc4RBQaGfzCxXrGg2N4gG4MDC0yfEo2AmzRJC37lvN4wQA3XDYAEyTsKaySEgxEgAB7BToAHS6YlO2HGWR6RmCj2W7QgjHYRBogOBIPikGglwA1vhcCt8PiYABpJAATwgAHktABlIjeIjmBkIABWAG0ALqw7JILLEdmcnnI7bzQrQAnE0nkynQLncpCUU70Ii0xiLGn0pms8XiVXBIl03BaaDa3WW4rGsSq+gXK4c25gL5fQ5GGiIwT6xkstkkDkmnmJTAMe0hiXc4JimNhvmIwXJeiI0bUACiYGAPo9XpsJ3oU1w43a0TENATocd4dOaXYyxockKMniGCbDxkLlw7S8JHbQA) a playground with the solution I found):

```
class Label {
  constructor(
    public name: string = 'name',
    public configPath: string = 'path',
    public foo: { bar: string } = { bar: 'hello' }
  ) {
  }
}

const labelName: string = 'bob'
const configPath: string = './path/to/a/config.file'
const label_name = new Label(labelName, configPath);

function line(line: string): void {
  const regex = /\./g;
  let path = (line.split(regex)as unknown)as KeysOfStartingObj[];
  let startingObj = (label_name as unknown)as Object;

  type KeysOfStartingObj = keyof typeof startingObj
  function addPath(path: KeysOfStartingObj) {
    startingObj = startingObj[path];
  }
  path.forEach(addPath);
  console.log(startingObj);
}

line('name')
line('foo.bar')
```

So basically TS was complaining because it didn't know much about the `startingObj` keys. So by doing `type KeysOfStartingObj = keyof typeof startingObj` I am creating a type which is the union of the keys in `startingObj`, then with `let path = (line.split(regex)as unknown)as KeysOfStartingObj[];` I tell TS that the splitted string array is an array of `KeysOfStartingObj`. In the function signature as well I am telling TS that the arg `path` will be of the same type. So TS stops yelling at me =) .

I will work on the function a little better cause at the moment it assumes that anything inside the `path` array is a key of `startingObj`, which is not true, as I could pass in some values which are not part of the object. But that was not the scope of my question. I just wanted to find a way to have TS stop giving that error. I have same errore in other places of my code and I now know how yo solve it! I hope this can be helpful to others!