# Unusual syntax to create object method from a single item string array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux-actions

I come cross this [redux-actions tutorial](https://redux-actions.js.org/docs/introduction/Tutorial.html), and I noticed a unusual syntax to create an object method:

```
const stringArray = ["STRING_ARRAY"];

const strangeObject = {
  [stringArray]() {
    console.log(stringArray);
  }
};
```

Can someone name or explain the syntax feature in use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a mix of two features of `ES6`.

You can have computed property in an object:

```
const b = "foo";
const a = {
    [b]: true
};

// same as
const a = {};
a[b] = true;
```

There is also a shorthand for functions:

```
const a = {
    b() { console.log("foo");}
};

// same as
const a = {
    b: function() { console.log("foo");}
};
```

If you mix the two, you get what you have: a method whose name is a computed value. Here your object will be the same as

```
const strangeObject = {
    STRING_ARRAY: function() {
        console.log("STRING_ARRAY");
    }
};
```

---

Whenever a computed value for an object is not a string, as in your case, it will be converted to a string.

In your case

```
["STRING_ARRAY"].toString() === "STRING_ARRAY"
```

so it does not change much.

Comment: In your example (`[b]: true`), `b` is a string. What allows it to be an array and still work, like in OP's example?

Comment: It's `["STRING_ARRAY"].toString() === "STRING_ARRAY"`

Comment: ^this and I think `String(["STRING_ARRAY"])` is more appropriate since you can do `[null]: true` and null doesn't have `.toString()`

Comment: @mdatsev ES6 allows [non-string object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings).