# Why does JS allow property access with an array as key?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Suppose I have an object

```
obj = {
  a : 1
}
```

I'm able to access property `a` via `obj["a"]` but I'm also able to access it via `obj[["a"]]`. How is that possible?

Comment: Related: [Keys in Javascript objects can only be strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6066846/4642212), [Using Object as key results always in value of last assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53668796/4642212).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Object keys are always strings (or, rarely, symbols). When you do

```
obj[<expression>]
```

the interpreter will try to turn `expression` into a valid key, if it isn't one already. In this case, turning `["a"]` into a string results in `"a"`, so both `obj["a"]` and `obj[["a"]]` work.

(When an array is implicitly turned into a primitive, like here, it gets `.join`ed by a comma, and `["a"].join(',') === "a"`)

Comment: I had never realised JS was casting types as deep as it can in nested arrays: `[[[["a"]]]] == "a"` evaluates to `true`

Comment: While we are on it, why does JS do it this way?

Comment: @YogeshGupta As opposed to what, throwing an error? Some of it has to do with JS being loosely typed - the interpreter may *try* to do type conversions automatically to get to a result without throwing. It's kind of confusing, which is why I prefer Typescript, which will forbid such implicit casting