# Object.keys using numbers in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

```
type Foo = { [key: number]: string }

const foo: Foo = { 100: 'foo', 200: 'bar' }
const sizes: number[] = Object.keys(foo)
```

Gives me:

> `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]`

Why does Typescript assume `string[]`? And what is the correct way of creating an array of numbers here?

Comment: A more detailed explanation is available in this answer (check the question for more context as well): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6066954/1364793

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All keys are strings in JavaScript - just use `map`:

```
const sizes: number[] = Object.keys(foo).map(Number);
```

This'll only work for numeric strings - if it's a European string involving decimals, for instance, it'll be `NaN`, and that *never* ends well.

```js
console.log(Number("10,7"));
```

Or change either of your types:

```
const sizes: string[] = Object.keys(foo);
```

Or:

```
type Foo = { [key: string]: string };
```

Answer (score 6):

Object properties names are always string, if you want to convert property names to numbers on the fly, you can use `map(Number)`:

```
const sizes: number[] = Object.keys(foo).map(Number);
```

Pay attention because, if your property name can't be converter to number, you'll get `NaN` in your sizes array

Answer (score 6):

> Why does Typescript assume string[]? And what is the correct way of
>   creating an array of numbers here?

Because object property names are always strings (or, to properly explain that, are always **coerced** to strings), hence the default signature assumes a `string[]` as default type, as the intellisense even suggests:

[image]

Besides, **you can't ensure that, at runtime, those keys will be numbers**. Defining a type that strictly defines that object to have numeric keys **has no effect at runtime**, hence it's **always** safer to safely cast the values to the desired type:

```
const sizes: number[] = Object.keys(foo).map(Number); // beware of possible NaN here.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` always returns an array of *strings*:

```js
const obj = { prop: 'prop' };
console.log(typeof Object.keys(obj)[0]);
```

Keys are always strings, even numeric keys like with arrays and with your `Foo` object - if you use a numeric key rather than a string key, it'll be coerced to a string automatically.

I'd use `[key: string]` instead, because that's what the type of the keys are internally.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Object has no number keys! All keys are Strings. Always.If you want to map other things to values you should use a `map`.

```js
var numObj = { 1:'one', 2:'two' };
var numObjKey = Object.keys(numObj);

console.log(typeof numObjKey[0]);
console.log(typeof numObjKey.map(Number)[0]);
```