# creating function names dynamically

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic function name in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript)

I want to achieve the below result .Can someone tell me how.Basically name is dynamic.

```
 var name =  'tab'+ ID;    
name(tab);
```

So far tried stuff which works fine.Is it a good way of doing or else somebody can suggest another way.

```
var function_name  =  't'+ ID; 
if (typeof(window[function_name]) === "function")
{
    window[function_name](tab);
}
```

Comment: Note that the above only works if the function being called is in the global scope, or if you explicitly put it there.

Answer (score 2):

I'd first create an object to store your functions:

```
var funcs = {};
```

Then you can just use bracket notation:

```
var id = '001';

funcs['tab'+ id] = function(tab) {

};

funcs.tab001(tab);
// or if you have special chars...
funcs['tab001'](tab);
```