# "Good" practices to implement declare() function

Tags: javascript, object, definitions

## Introduction

Currently I'm being curious about implementation of `declare()` function, that should allow me to declare javascript classes with usage of prototypal inheritance (or a sort of it, because javascript using different object model, not classic OOP). So far, I found some issues, on which I would like to know somebody's opinion and clarification (if possible).

Here is a *"reproduction script"* (**simplified** to reproduce issues), that can be executed in console:

```
function namespace(){
    if(arguments.length > 1){
        var m, map, result;

        for(m = 0; map = arguments[m], m < arguments.length; m++){
            result = namespace(map);
        }

        return result;
    }

    var scope = window,
        parts = arguments[0].split('.'),
        part, p;

    for(p = 0; part = parts[p], p < parts.length; p++){

        if(typeof scope[part] === 'undefined'){
            scope[part] = {};
        }

        scope = scope[part];
    }

    return scope;
}

function inherit(child, parent){
    child.prototype = Object.create(parent);
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
    child.prototype.$parent = parent.prototype;
}

function mixin(target, source){
    var value;

    target = target || {};

    if(typeof source == 'object'){
        for(var property in source){    
            target[property] = source[property];
        }
    }

    return target;
}

function extend(){
    var mixins = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0),
        object = mixins.shift() || {},
        length = mixins.length,
        m, mixin;

    for(m = 0; mixin = mixins[m], m < length; mixin(object, mixin), m++);

    return object;
}

function declare(config){
    var map  = config.object.split('.'),
        name = map.pop(),
        ns   = namespace(map.join('.'));

    ns[name] = function(){
        this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    if(config.parent){
        if(typeof config.parent == 'string'){
            config.parent = namespace(config.parent);
        }

        inherit(ns[name], config.parent);
    }

    if(config.mixins){
        extend.apply(null, [ ns[name].prototype ].concat(config.mixins));
    }

    if(config.definition){
        mixin(ns[name].prototype, config.definition);
    }
}

declare({
    object: 'Test.A',
    definition: {
        constructor: function(){
            this.a = 1;
        },

        test: function(){
            return this.a;
        }
    }
});

declare({
    object: 'Test.B',
    parent: 'Test.A',
    definition: {
        constructor: function(){
            this.$parent.constructor.call(this);
            this.b = 1;
        },

        test: function(){
            return this.$parent.test.call(this) + this.b;
        }
    }
});

declare({
    object: 'Test.C',
    definition: {
        x: 1
    }
});

var a = new Test.A(),
    b = new Test.B();

console.log('a.test() = ' + a.test());
console.log('b.test() = ' + b.test());

// var c = new Test.C();
```

---

## A concept

`declare()` should merge functionality of `extend()`, `inherit()` and `mixin()` functions. As an argument it takes a `config` object with following sections:

1. *object* - object class name (required);
2. *parent* - object class name to inherit (not required);
3. *mixins* - objects / classes, which properties and method needs to be included to the prototype of result class / object (not required);
4. *definition* - result class prototype properties and methods.

---

## The issues

---

**#1 issue** is about constructor: if `config.definition` comes without `constructor` method, then I'm getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error, which means, that my "temporary" constructor function

```
ns[name] = function(){
    this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Started calling itself in endless loop. To reproduce you may uncomment `var c = new Test.C();` line.

**Questions:** *Should I test `config.definition` on `constructor` method existence and inject an empty function, where there is no `constructor` method specified to avoid this? Is there any other possible approaches without significant performance impact?*

---

**#2 issue** is about debugging: when I'm trying to log `a` or `b` variables then I'm getting `ns.(anonymous function){ ... }` in console, which means, that I've lost namespace and class / object name, while performed a "dynamic declaration".

```
ns[name] = function(){ ... };
```

Possibly, that the problem in anonymous function without name, so browser tries to save last symbols, where an assignment occurs. I was hoping, that there is a possibility to create function dynamicly and define name for it, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript), which suggests to use `eval();` or `new Function(...)();`.

**Questions:** *Is there any possibility to save namespace and classname without any `evUl()` magic?*

For example, here is what I would appreciate:

```
namespace('X.Y');

X.Y.Z = function(){ this.a = 1 };

var test = new X.Y.Z();

console.log(test);
```

Shows:

```
X.Y.Z {a: 1}
^^^^^
Literaly, what I want to achieve.
```

---

*I do really appreciate your help efforts. Thanks.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I test config.definition on constructor method existence and inject an empty function, where there is no constructor method specified to avoid this? Is there any other possible approaches without significant performance impact?

Yes, injecting an empty function as the constructor would actually *reduce* performance impact.

And instead of a `function(){this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);}` wrapper you should just use the constructor itself (unless you're not sure that it doesn't return an object):

```
ns[name] = config.definition && config.definition.constructor || function(){};
```

---

> Is there any possibility to save namespace and classname without any eval() magic?

No. What your debugger/inspector uses here for describing instances is the [`.name` of the constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). You cannot set that other by using a named function, and those cannot contain dots in their names.

---

**#3 issue** is your `inherits` function. Instead of

```
child.prototype = Object.create(parent);
```

it needs to be

```
child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
```

Comment: Hi there, and Thanks. Except #3 issue, everything works as I believe it should be. Is it critical ?

Comment: What is critical, issue 3? What works, your code or my suggestions?

Comment: Well, what works: `constructor` works - it is allowing to call inherited constructor. Aboun issue #2 I just wasn't sure if it is possible, and as much I read, I find it almost impossible. About issue #3, I'm currently investigating it. I'm just asking, if you could explain it further, little bit?