# How to connect function name with var javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to connect function name with var javascript ?

i want to connect `myFunction` with var `zz`.

i try to like this but not work, how can i do that ?

```
<script>
for(var zz = 0; zz < 3; zz++)
{
    function myFunction'+var zz+'() {
         -------------SOME CODEING---------------
        } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Define function outside of the loop, pass a param into its call (`myFunction(zz);`).

Comment: you may use eval() but no good practive at all

Comment: dynamic function names? That is NEVER a good idea...

Comment: Avoid to use it. But.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript

Comment: I smell a bad practice. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "connect function name with var"?

Comment: @FelixKling, he wants functions named like `myFunc1`, `myFunc2`, `myFunc3`, etc. by looping a variable.

Comment: Dont repeat yourself ;-D

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a good way of doing this is to store your functions in an object and then reference those in your loop:

```
var obj = {
    fn0: function () {
        console.log(0);
    },
    fn1: function () {
        console.log(1);
    },
    fn2: function () {
        console.log(2);
    }
}

for (var zz = 0; zz < 3; zz++) {
  var fnName = 'fn' + zz;
  obj[fnName]();
}
```

Or perhaps even better:

```
for (var zz = 0, l = Object.keys(obj).length; zz < l; zz++) {
  var fnName = 'fn' + zz;
  obj[fnName]();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/20owuctb/)