# Extend javascript classes and wrap them in a container object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, containers, extends

In **ES6** you can have your custom classes extend javascript built-in objects. Like this you can make `Array`, `Number`, `String`, `Date` objects with custom methods.

I Was experimenting with this and tried to wrap my objects inside a container object called `My`, simply following the example [here from MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends). But when I define my custom `Date` class inside the object like this:

```
var My = {};

class My.Date extends Date {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getFormattedDate() {
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    return this.getDate() + "-" + months[this.getMonth()] + "-" + this.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

I get the following **SyntaxError**:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

**[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/jy9pt1yk/)** that demonstrates this.

I bet there is some way to work around this but I am not sure how to do that...

Comment: You can't use a `.` in your classname.

Comment: Check [link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) for official information about Identifier Names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be wrapping the logic in a function so that the new class is declared in the functions local scope and then adding it to the global `My` container inside the function.
Like this you can use the customized objects (extended primitives) without messing with the global objects and they will still look similar (For example the class name is `Date` when printed in console).

```
var My = {};

function init(){

    class Date extends window.Date {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        getFormattedDate() {
            var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
            return this.getDate() + "-" + months[this.getMonth()] + "-" + this.getFullYear();
        }
    }

    My.Date = Date;

}

init();

Date === window.Date; // true
My.Date === window.Date; // false
My.Date.name // Date -> class name
new My.Date().getFormattedDate(); // 2-Jun-2016
```

---

Another solution from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611096/1697459):

```
var My = {};

My.Date = class extends Date {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    getFormattedDate() {
        var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
        return this.getDate() + "-" + months[this.getMonth()] + "-" + this.getFullYear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed to use `.`'s in your classname. But it is possible to add the class instance to your namespace.

```
var My = {};

class MyDate extends Date {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getFormattedDate() {
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    return this.getDate() + "-" + months[this.getMonth()] + "-" + this.getFullYear();
  }
}

My.Date = MyDate;
```

Or directly

```
var My = {};

My.Date = class MyDate extends Date {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getFormattedDate() {
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    return this.getDate() + "-" + months[this.getMonth()] + "-" + this.getFullYear();
  }
}
```