# Typing the return of a Factory method that applies mixins based on arguments

Tags: typescript, generics, factory-pattern

Am trying to create a Factory method in TypeScript that creates a class (instance) with some mixins applied, based on one of the arguments of the Factory method.

This is code being ported from plain JavaScript. Functionally it works fine, its just that TypeScript doesn't 'recognize' the dynamic stuff that is happening, thus it doesn't know the returnType of the factory method.

This is the code I currently have and I'm trying to make TypeScript somehow know returnType of the ServiceFactory method, which is at least always BaseModel, but depending on the value for the operations parameter, also is augmented with interfaces like ICreatable.

```js
const OPERATIONS = Object.freeze({
  /** Only HTTP GET support (methods: all and show) */
  DEFAULT: 0,
  /** HTTP POST (method: create */
  CREATE: 1,
  /** HTTP PATCH (method: update */
  UPDATE: 2,
  /** both HTTP POST & PATCH  (methods: create & update */
  CREATE_AND_UPDATE: 3,
  /** HTTP PUT (method: replace */
  REPLACEABLE: 4,
  /** HTTP DELETE (method: delete */
  DELETE: 8,
  /** HTTP GET, POST, PUT, PATCH & DELETE (methods: all, show, create, replace, update & delete) */
  ALL: 15,
});

type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export interface ICreatable {
  create(requestContext:object, body: object, options:object): Promise<object>
}

export class BaseModel {}

export const Creatable = <T extends Constructor<BaseModel>>(Sup: T) => class extends Sup implements ICreatable {
  async create(): Promise<object> {
    return ...;
  }
};

export function ServiceFactory(name: string, operations = OPERATIONS.DEFAULT): BaseModel {
  let Clazz = { [name]: class extends BaseModel {} }[name]; // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605775/es6-dynamic-class-names/33611096

  //if (operations & OPERATIONS.UPDATE) {
  //  Clazz = Updatable(Clazz);
  //}
  if (operations & OPERATIONS.CREATE) {
    Clazz = Creatable(Clazz);
  }
  //if (operations & OPERATIONS.DELETE) {
  //  Clazz = Deletable(Clazz);
  //}
  //if (operations & OPERATIONS.REPLACEABLE) {
  //  Clazz = Replaceable(Clazz);
  //}

  return new Clazz();
}
```

When I'd call the code below, TypeScript should know that someNameClassInstance has a method called 'create'

```js
const someNameClassInstance = ServiceFactory('someName', OPERATIONS.CREATE)
someNameClassInstance. //auto complete should yield 'create'
``
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your use case, and the need for dynamic classes, but how about using generics for a quick solution:

```
export function ServiceFactory<T extends BaseModel>(name: string, operations = OPERATIONS.DEFAULT): T {
}
```

```
type MyType = {create: (oneArg: string, otherArg: number) => boolean}

const someNameClassInstance = ServiceFactory<MyType>('someName', OPERATIONS.CREATE)
someNameClassInstance // yields code insight create
```

for a more solid solution I think refactoring factory itself is the way to go.