# Multiple classes that have a different name but extends the same class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop

I have for example this class:

```
abstract class MyClass {
  abstract myProp: number;

  constructor() {
    // Some code
  }
}
```

So I want to create multiple classes that extends this class. But I don't want to repeat it multiple times as I will have a lot of classes. So the purpose is that each class has a different name and myProp.

For example:

```
class FirstClass extends MyClass {
  myProp = 1;
  constructor() {
    super();
    // Some code
  }
}

class SecondClass extends MyClass {
  myProp = 2;
  constructor() {
    super();
    // Some code
  }
}
```

So I want to generate these classes (with for example a function) but the problem is that I will have to use the **new** keyword.
So the usage for each of these classes should be like this:

```
const myConst = new FirstClass();
const myConst2 = new SecondClass();
```

I hope this makes some sense. I just don't want to repeat every class because it has a different name and myProp.

Comment: If all that changes is a property, can't you just pass that into the constructor?

Comment: No each class should have a different name, so I can't do this...

Answer (score 2):

You can create classes through a function that returns an anonymous class.

```
const createClass = ( prop: number ) => {
    return class extends MyClass {
        myProp: number;

        constructor () {
            super();
            this.myProp = prop;
        }
    }
}

const FirstClass = createClass(1);

const x = new FirstClass();
console.log(x.myProp);
```

Or check out the answers to these questions for ideas:

- [ES6 Dynamic class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605775/es6-dynamic-class-names)
- [Create object from class name in JavasScript ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776949/create-object-from-class-name-in-javasscript-ecmascript-6)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could just pass the variable that's different as an argument in the constructor.

```
class MyClass {
  myProp: number;

  constructor(myProp: number) {
    this.myProp = myProp
    // Some code
  }
}
```

And then create the class instances you want.

```
const myConst = new MyClass(1);
const myConst2 = new MyClass(2);
```

Personally, I would only extend a class if I want to add some methods or properties that aren't shared. Since `myProp` exists in both classes, it's probably better to just pass the value to the constructor.

Comment: No each class should have a different name, so I can't do this...

Comment: Could you explain me why they should have different class names?