# Class syntax with parametrized class name

Tags: javascript, typescript, metaprogramming

I want create classes dynamicaly in runtime, and I want parametrize the class name.

```js
function newClass(className:string) {
   return class MyDynamicClass { }
}

// expected class name: "Person"
let personClass = newClass("Person")

// expected class name: "Contact"
let contactClass = newClass("Contact")
```

P.S.: The proposed duplicate question ([ES6 Dynamic class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605775/es6-dynamic-class-names)) is with wrong accepted answer and other answers does not fulfil my requirements.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: @Dai It's usefull to see the descriptive class names in stack traces. its very helpful, if you see "Person.getContacts" instead of "DynamicClass.getContacts". Espetially in larger domain models.

Comment: Where are you seeing `DynamicClass.getContacts`?

Comment: @Dai In `error.trace`.

Comment: @jcalz result is the same as mine. OP wants `personClass` to be `class SomeName {}` instead of just `class {}`

Comment: @captain-yossarian ah yeah I see.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to make dynamic class name like here:

```js
class [className] {}
```

It is not allowed.
However, you can create an object with `className` property ([class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#class_expressions)):

```js
const newClass = (className: string) => ({
  [className]: class { }
}[className])

// expected class name: "Person"
let personClass = newClass("Person")
personClass.name // Person
```

I know, `personClass` returns `class {}` without name. I think this is the closest working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can try `eval` or `new Function` but ot is considered a bad practice