# classes with class X {} VS const X = class {}

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Different ways of defining, but what's the difference?

```js
class A {}

const B = class {}

const C = class {
    static define() {
        /* do some code */

        return this // the class itself, as it is a static method
    }
}.define()
```

I would expect the problem to be in B and C then A to just work, but A and B works fine, and C just doesn't.

When I log them, I get the classes. But if I log their `name` property:

```js
class A {}

const B = class {}

const C = class {
    static define() {
        /* do some code */

        return this // the class itself, as it is a static method
    }
}.define()

console.log('A -', A.name) //output: "A - A"
console.log('B -', B.name) //output: "B - B"
console.log('C -', C.name) //output: "C -"
```

I'm bit confused. If `const` holds just the value (class), how does it give a name. Or if it's variable's name or something similar, why wouldn't it work with a returned value in C then?

I tried to research but couldn't find an article.
Then I made tests. Results were unexpected (they're included in the question).
I expect someone to explain what is going on here. It's a really subtle thing. But the class is treated like an anonymous class in one way, and the other is like a normal class, which I didn't expect to be. The classic way works just fine, but this, I really wonder this.

Comment: Your question doesn't match the title; you seem to be asking about differing behaviour between two forms of [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) **not** the difference between that and a [class statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class).

Comment: yeah you are right. I've changed the title.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I couldn't find an explanation for `C` in your links. But yes, it's more about classes than modules.

Comment: Your title still doesn't match, the examples you seem to be contrasting (B and C) _both_ use `const X = class` syntax (the expression not the statement).

Comment: @jonrsharpe it matches the examples `B.name` returns `'B'` for me, but `C.name` returns `''`

Comment: This should answer the question [How do I write a named arrow function in ES2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski right, but they're _both anonymous class expressions_, neither uses the `class X {}` syntax the title refers to. A doesn't actually seem to be relevant to the question.

Comment: We should change the title then

Comment: "*A and B works fine, and C just doesn't.*" - what's the problem? `C` works as well, I don't get a syntax error or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the second syntax is in fact more like this:

```js
const C = (() => class {})()
console.log(C.name)
```

That's why js engine can't determine function's name

How to fix it based on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132163/5089567)?

```js
const C = (() => class {})()
Object.defineProperty(C, 'name', {
  value: 'C'
});
console.log(C.name)
```

```js
const C = class {
    static define() {
        return this
    }
}.define()
Object.defineProperty (C, 'name', {value: 'C'});
console.log(C.name)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought.  But `B` working just confused me. now I understood. Is there a way to make `C` work? Or I can't export a programatically made class?

Comment: @FLAW this seems like a code smell: I can't think of any *good* reason code will rely on the `name` property of a class. There are, however, plenty of *bad* reasons that will make the code brittle and unreliable. As your code seems to be if you require a way to patch over the lack of `name`. At its core, you shouldn't have to rely on unreliable information. Note that even if you patch over the `name` property, then you have *further problems* - classes can have *the same name*. If you rely on the names being there, I suspect duplicate names would also be an issue.

Comment: @VLAZ it wasn't only about the `name`, but I was scared cuz it looks like `B` and `C` isn't the same. Maybe there's something else that I'm missing.

Comment: it kinda comforts me: `class C_{static define(){return this}}
const C = C_.define()
let [c, c_] = [new C(), new C_()]
console.log(c instanceof C, c instanceof C_, '\n', c_ instanceof C, c_ instanceof C_)
`

Comment: @FLAW `B` and `C` are the same. Except one has a name, the other doesn't. Both are normal classes - if you add properties and/or methods to them, both would have them.

Comment: @VLAZ but `console.log(B === C) // false`

Comment: @FLAW well *obviously they are not the same class*!!! They are, however, constructed exactly the same, and there would be no actual difference how you initialise them. Except the `name` property. I thought it was quite clear from the context that I do not consider them to be one and the same class. If *you* did, then you should have probably led with that. No, they aren't the same. `C` has that static method which `B` has which is a big giveaway they are not one thing.

Comment: oh gosh I felt so stupid. I dunno what I was thinking about when I wrote `===`. I understand you. so, there is nothing more than having `name` or not right?