# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: npm, webpack, commonjs, webpack-2, package.json

I've started using webpack2 (to be precise, `v2.3.2`) and after re-creating my config I keep running into an issue I can't seem to solve I get (sorry in advance for ugly dump):

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components/DoISuportIt' in '[absolute path to my repo]/src'
resolve 'components/DoISuportIt' in '[absolute path to my repo]/src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: [absolute path to my repo]/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    aliased with mapping 'components': '[absolute path to my repo]/src/components' to '[absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt'
      using description file: [absolute path to my repo]/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      after using description file: [absolute path to my repo]/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: [absolute path to my repo]/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/DoISuportIt)
          as directory
            [absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt doesn't exist
          no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            [absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt doesn't exist
          .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            [absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt.js doesn't exist
          .jsx
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            [absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt.jsx doesn't exist
[[absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt]
[[absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt]
[[absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt.js]
[[absolute path to my repo]/src/components/DoISuportIt.jsx]
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --display-error-details"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

In terms of the `browser` field it's complaining about, the documentation I've been able to find on this is: [`package-browser-field-spec`](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec). There is also webpack documentation for it, but it seems to have it turned on by default: [`aliasFields: ["browser"]`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-aliasfields). I tried adding a `browser` field to my `package.json` but that didn't seem to do any good.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
import path from 'path';
const source = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

export default {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: source,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: source,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            query: {
              importLoader: 1,
              localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**src/main.js**

```js
import DoISuportIt from 'components/DoISuportIt';
```

**src/components/DoISuportIt/index.jsx**

```js
export default function() { ... }
```

For completeness, `.babelrc`

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "latest",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-css-modules"
  ],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "compact": true,
      "comments": false,
      "minified": true
    }
  },
  "sourceMaps": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: I love all the "in my case" answers. Just goes to show how terrible of a tool Webpack still is. Imagine returning a single generic error for various "in my case" scenarios!

Comment: I still don't understand Webpack after years of using it

Comment: for me, I had put `resolve` in `modules` instead of the root config

Comment: I have never seen a worst error than this. trying from last 2 hours still not able to figure out what can be cause!!

Answer (score 343, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with Webpack just not resolving an import - talk about horrible horrible error messages :(

```js
// I Had to change:
import DoISuportIt from 'components/DoISuportIt';

// to (notice the missing `./`)
import DoISuportIt from './components/DoISuportIt';
```

Comment: Is the issue caused by npm ? Today I upgraded a module using npm, by uninstalling and installing a latest version of module, Now I got this error and the error tells to change the relative location of module, but the list of files is bit high, what caused all these files to change its relative position?

Comment: This also saved my ass. It's somewhat counter intuitive that in the sass files you can import with 'folder' but in .js files you need to do it like './folder' . Also without --display-error-details there's NO error message what so ever, it just crashes

Comment: @Matthew Herbst one of the stupidest error messages:) my ass is saved, thx!

Comment: Similarly, when using Karma-webpack I had to use a ./ where I didn't expect to.  `    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/angulartics$/, './angulartics.mock.ts'),`

Comment: Is there some configuration for the automatic relative-to-absolute paths conversion while compilation form less ? I have a 3rd-party app (calendar) which on `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config examples/webpack.config.js` throws the same and I don't want to monkey-patch. (I also noticed the funny of 4chan-like up-votes in this comments - all of them are equally +1 LOL)

Comment: Still in almost 2022 in webpack 5 the same terrible error messages. No progress from v4 to v5 in thi way?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but I still want to use @ as the path.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70902895/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration-when-i-changed-the-i @Matthew Herbst

Comment: Cleary there is no right answer.  This means that webpack has done a terrible job with error handling and need to make improvements.

Answer (score 85):

Just for record, because I had similiar problem, and maybe this answer will help someone: in my case I was using library which was using `.js` files and I didn't had such extension in webpack resolve extensions. Adding proper extension fixed problem:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  }
}
```

Comment: Silly me.. I forgot to add the resolver property. Thank you :)

Answer (score 39):

I'm building a React server-side renderer and found this can also occur when building a separate server config from scratch. If you're seeing this error, try the following:

1. Make sure your `entry` value is properly pathed relative to your `context` value. Mine was missing the preceeding `./` before the entry file name.
2. Make sure you have your `resolve` value included. Your imports on anything in `node_modules` will default to looking in your `context` folder, otherwise.

Example:

```js
const serverConfig = {
name: 'server',
context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
entry: {serverEntry: ['./server-entry.js']},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'server.js',
    publicPath: 'public/',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
},
module: {
    rules: [/*...*/]
},
resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ]
},
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ]
}
};
```

Answer (score 28):

I encountered this error in a TypeScript project. In my `webpack.config.js` file I was only resolving TypeScript files i.e.

```js
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"],
}
```

However I noticed that the node_module which was causing the error:

> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

did not have any ".ts" files (which is understandable as the module has been converted to vanilla JS. Doh!).

So to fix the issue I updated the `resolve` declaration to:

```js
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
}
```

Comment: You can also use "..." at the end of extensions to include the defaults.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue, but mine was because of wrong casing in path:

```
// Wrong - uppercase C in /pathCoordinate/
./path/pathCoordinate/pathCoordinateForm.component

// Correct - lowercase c in /pathcoordinate/
./path/pathcoordinate/pathCoordinateForm.component
```

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your `package.json`:

```js
"browser": {
  "[module-name]": false   
},
```

Comment: i coder should read the documentation first, i always search in stackoverflow but nowadays i prefer to read documentation first. thanks for editing...

Comment: I have solved the problem with the main.js, neverthless I have the next error: **Error during loading: Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js line 110252** Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @kimo_ouz -  Absolutely brilliant! Thank you for introducing me to the "browser" field world. Here are some links for other interested people: [insides of the webpack-package.json relationship](https://www.jonathancreamer.com/how-webpack-decides-what-entry-to-load-from-a-package-json/) and [NPM official notes](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#browser)

Answer (score 9):

This also occurs when the `webpack.config.js` is simply missing (dockerignore ‍♂️)

Comment: when running `npm run build` i had to modify the build script in `package.json` to reference the correct webpack configuration file `"build": "webpack --mode production --config webpack/webpack.config.prod.js";`

Comment: I also saw this when someone accidentally had `webpackconfig.js` instead of `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 7):

I changed my entry to:

```js
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/index.js'),
```

and it worked.

Comment: changed it from what?

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was a package that was installed as a dependency in `package.json` with a relative path like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
  // ...
  "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html"
},
```

and imported in `js/app.js` with `import "phoenix_html"`

This had worked but after an update of node, npm, etc... it failed with the above error-message.

Changing the import line to `import "../../deps/phoenix_html"` fixed it.

Comment: Oh no, why Webpack is so unintuitive at this, your thoughts? I also have local dependency.

Answer (score 6):

My case was rather embarrassing: I added a typescript binding for a JS library without adding the library itself.

So if you do:

```sh
npm install --save @types/lucene
```

Don't forget to do:

```
npm install --save lucene
```

Kinda obvious, but I just totally forgot and that cost me quite some time.

Answer (score 6):

I had aliases into `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@store/*": ["./src/store/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

So **I solved this issue by adding aliases to `webpack.config` also**:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@store': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/store'),
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, to the very end of the `webpack.config.js`, where I should `exports` the config, there was a typo: `export`(should be `exports`), which led to failure with loading `webpack.config.js` at all.

```js
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: "./lib/components/Index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
            }
        ]
    }
}

// pay attention to "export!s!" here
module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 5):

I got same problem and fixed with adding file extension.

```js
// Old:
import RadioInput from './components/RadioInput'

// New:
import RadioInput from './components/RadioInput.vue'
```

Also, if you still want to use without extensions, you can add this webpack config: (Thanx for @matthew-herbst for the info)

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.wasm'], // Add your extensions here.
  },
};
```

Comment: You should be able to not need the extension if you pass the custom `resolve.extensions`: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error and I didn't want absolute imports. My normal relative import was not working with the same error and "module not found".

I was missing this in my webpack config.

```js
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone building an ionic app and trying to upload it. Make sure you added at least one platform to the app. Otherwise you will get this error.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, this error was as a result of improper naming of aliases in Webpack.
In that I had an alias named `redux` and webpack tried looking for the `redux` that comes with the redux package in my alias path.

To fix this, I had to rename the alias to something different like `Redux`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was due to a broken symlink when trying to npm link a custom angular library to consuming app. After running npm link `@authoring/canvas`

```json
"@authoring/canvas": "path/to/ui-authoring-canvas/dist"
```

It appear everything was OK but the module still couldn't be found:

[image: Error from npm link]

When I corrected the import statement to something that the editor could find Link:

```js
import {CirclePackComponent} from '@authoring/canvas/lib/circle-pack/circle-pack.component';
```

I received this which is mention in the overflow thread:

[image: Field Browser doesn't contain a valid alias configuration]

To fix this I had to:

1. `cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/packageName`
2. `cd ..`
3. `rm -rf packageName`
4. In the root directory of the library, run:

```
a) rm -rf dist
b) npm run build
c) cd dist 
d) npm link
```

5. In the consuming app, update the `package.json` with:

```json
"packageName": "file:/path/to/local/node_module/packageName""
```

6. In the root directory of the consuming app run npm link packageName

Answer (score 3):

In my case (lolz),

I was importing a local package (that I was developing, and building with rollup) via NPM/Yarn link, into another package I was developing. The imported package was a load of React components, and was configured to have a peerDependency of `react` and `react-dom`.

The consuming package was being built with Webpack and obviously wasn't correctly feeding the installed `react` and `react-dom` libraries into my local dependency as it was compiling it.

I adjusted my webpack configuration to indicate it should alias those peer dependencies to the correct dependencies in the consuming package:

```js
/* ... */

resolve: {
  extensions: [/* make sure you have them all correct here, as per other answers */],
  alias: {
    react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
    'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom')
  }
},

/* ... */
```

Obviously you need to import `path` in the `webpack.config.js` file in order to use the methods seen above.

A more detailed explanation can be found in [this article](https://penx.medium.com/managing-dependencies-in-a-node-package-so-that-they-are-compatible-with-npm-link-61befa5aaca7)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using invalid templateUrl.By correcting it problem solved.

```
@Component({
        selector: 'app-edit-feather-object',
        templateUrl: ''
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

My case was similar to @witheng's answer.

At some point, I noticed some casing error in some file names in my development environment. For example the file name was

```
type.ts
```

and I renamed it to

```
Type.ts
```

In my Mac dev environment this didn't register as a change in git so this change didn't go to source control.

In the Linux-based build machine where the filenames are case-sensitive it wasn't able to find the file with different casing.

To avoid issues like this in the future, I ran this command in the repo:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Comment: Volkan, how can I get in touch with you? You website has no email on it. Want to ask a question about one of your blog posts, namely https://volkanpaksoy.com/archive/2018/12/19/Monitoring-EC2-Instance-Disk-Space-with-AWS-CloudWatch/

Comment: @RobertBenedetto Probably easiest and most efficient way would be asking it here (or another StackExchange site if it's more relevant to your question) and post the link here. Then not only I can take a look but you'd probably get faster and better help from the entire community.

Comment: True. I'll do that. However, was just going to ask you to update it since the procedure for step 5 seems to have changed, and ask if there is any way to do step 6 using the AWS management site? I'm pretty entry level with AWS, and those two steps are very confusing.

Comment: Asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104686/adding-free-disk-space-metrics-to-aws-cloudwatch

Comment: It's been a while since I published that post and I don't really using EC2 instances at the moment. I wasn't aware of the changes. Hope somebody will be able to weigh in with the latest information. Have you also checked out the links in the resources section? If the resources in that post updated maybe you can get the latest info from them as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case,

I have mistakenly removed a library ("mini-create-react-context") from package.json. I added that back, and did yarn install and build the app and it start working properly. So please take a look at your package.json file once.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had accidentally imported this package while trying to use `process.env`:

```
import * as process from 'process';
```

Removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone with Ionic:
Updating to the latest @ionic/app-scripts version gave a better error message.

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

It was a wrong path for styleUrls in a component to a non-existing file.
Strangely it gave no error in development.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I did not have an export at the bottom of my webpack.config.js file. Simply adding

```
export default Config;
```

solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is due to a case-sensitivity typo in import path. For example,

Should be:

```
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/dashboard';
```

Instead of:

```
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/Dashboard';
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using single-spa, and encountered this issue with the error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/builds/**/**/src\main.single-spa.ts' in /builds/**/**'
```

I eventually figured out that in angular.json build options "main" was set to `src\\main.single-spa.ts`. Changing it to `src/main.single-spa.ts` fixed it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I imported library files like:

```
import { MyFile } from "my-library/public-api";
```

After I removed the public-api from the import everything worked fine:

```
import { MyFile } from "my-library";
```

MyFile is exported in the public-api file in the library.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running a GitHub action. The issue was because I'd listed the package as a peer dependency instead of a dependency.

Since I'm using Rollup, the solution was to install the package both as a peer dependency and a dev dependency, and use [rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external](https://github.com/pmowrer/rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external) to remove the dev dependency from the final build.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was, I was importing

```
.ts files into .js files
```

changing them to ts as well solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a mixture of `enum` and `interface` in the `index.d.ts` file.
I extracted enums into another file and the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `entry` field was missing under `module.exports` in webpack.config.js, causing this issue.

Comment: can some on answer this question if they have come across?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Webpack's **Module Federation** plugin:
I had a typo in the value of one of the fileds in the 'exposes' entry of the plugin.
Check your spelling:

```
exposes: {
            './ShopApp': './src/bootstrap' // check this value
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you run webpack serve and not specify the location of the configuration file.
For example:
Your package.json file

```json
"script": {
  "dev": "webpack serve"
}
```

But your webpack configs are in a config directory.So you should change the script:

```json
"script": {
  "dev": "webpack serve --config ./config/webpack.config.js"
}
```

Comment: ah i spent almost 3 hours just to figure out this. Webpack indeed should produce more informative error rather than generic like this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case(:p), I had a `.d.ts` file originally meant to contain definitions, but i defined an exported enum inside it. I was not resolving this file in webpack, since it only contained definition.

Moving enum to a separate .ts file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was a result of no entry point being found by webpack. If an entry point is not defined explicitly in your webpack config, the entry point is by default ./src/index.js
If such a path doesn't exist you will get this error.

To change the path to the entry point, use the entry setting in your config file (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#root).

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason, would be, if you have nullified a certain dependency in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
resolve: {
    fallback: {
        fs: false,
        path: false,
    },
},
```

You also need to add to `package.json`:

```js
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this fixed it. I changed this:

```
import {setupModel} from './setup-model.js';
```

To this:

```
import {setupModel} from './setup-model';
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a docker issue. I first deleted the webpack public compiled code and when that didn't work for whatever reason `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up` fixed the issue. I have to assume this is because I changed it from a `jsx` file to a `tsx` file and docker still remembered it as `jsx`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "@google-cloud/translate": "^5.1.4" and was truggling with this issue, until I tried this:

I opened google-gax\build\src\operationsClient.js file and changed

```
const configData = require('./operations_client_config');
```

to

```
const configData = require('./operations_client_config.json');
```

which solved the error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/operationsClient.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './operations_client_config' in 'C:\..\Projects\qaymni\node_modules\google-gax\build\src' resolve './operations_client_config' ......
```

I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with angular was importing

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core/core";
```

changed it to

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error:
**(I am using webpack 5 with React v18 and React Router v6)**

```sh
ERROR in ./src/components/App/App.jsx 5:0-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../Pages/Profile' in 'C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\src\components\App'  
resolve '../../Pages/Profile' in 'C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\src\components\App'
  using description file: C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\package.json (relative path: ./src/components/App)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\package.json (relative path: ./src/Pages/Profile)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\src\Pages\Profile doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\src\Pages\Profile.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\src\Pages\Profile.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\src\Pages\Profile.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\projects\webpack-starter-with-react\src\Pages\Profile doesn't exist
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-43 5:46-49

webpack 5.72.1 compiled with 3 errors in 1872 ms
```

Adding the file extension to the module import fixed this for me:

from this:

```js
import Home from '../../Pages/Home'
```

to this:

```js
import Home from '../../Pages/Home.jsx'
```

Comment: If you are using Babel you shouldn't have to do include file extensions here. Instead, add them as part of the `test` field in your Webpack `babel-loader` rule: `test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,`

Comment: Hi Matthew, this was already configured.

Comment: You are joking right? 

Answer (score 0):

On Windows PowerShell, the following command raises this error:

```
npx webpack .\src\js\main.js --output-filename output.js
```

The correct command is:

```
npx webpack ./src/js/main.js --output-filename output.js
```

Notice that when using `npx`, even on Windows, we have to use the Linux path separator (`/`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case :)

```bash
$ rm -rf tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
$ npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

I had quite funny solution with the same error, during development and I have deleted index.html from src folder.
But it has remained in dist folder as I had no webpack clean on dev serv launch.
Basically without index html dev serv will not work and will return you error posted above.
Soultion is to either add index.html or add different devserf default html file

Comment: You may like to also upvote the answer above from Ben H

Answer (score 0):

In my case I recently moved a TS library to output an esm module, I [read this guide](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c#how-can-i-make-my-typescript-project-output-esm), updated my `tsconfig.json` file to use `"module": "nodenext", "moduleResolution": "nodenext"`, and the module resolution was failing for the top index.ts with the same error. Interestingly though `tsc` was compiling the project successfully.

The solution was in this thread in the main webpack repo https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13252, in summary when there are 2 typescripts files `index.ts` and `foo.ts` where `index.ts` attempts to do `import foo from 'file.js'` (note the extension is `.js`) we should let webpack know that the extension `.js` should be mapped to both `.js` files and `.ts` files.

I added the following field `extensionAlias` to my webpack.config.js and it worked, **note that it's not the same as `extensions`**.

```
  resolve: {
    extensionAlias: {
      '.js': ['.ts', '.js'],
      '.mjs': ['.mts', '.mjs']
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with wrong "main" record in package.json of a package from which I was importing. Fixed it by changing `"main": "index.js"` to `"main": "dist/index.js"`