# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration AOT compilation error

Tags: angular, node-modules, angular2-aot, aot

I am trying to build my Angular project by AOT 
Running ng build --prod and am getting this as an error message.

> ERROR in Internal error: unknown identifier {"rethrowError":false}
>   ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src' resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src'   using
>   description file:
>   C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\package.json
>   (relative path: ./src)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file:
>   C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\package.json
>   (relative path: ./src)
>       using description file: C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\package.json
>   (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory)
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory
>   doesn't exist
>         .ts
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts
>   doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.js
>   doesn't exist
>         as directory
>           C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory
>   doesn't exist
>   [C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory]
>   [C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts]
>   [C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.js]
>   [C:\WorkingFolder\Development\admin-client-angular\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory]
>   @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74  @ multi ./src/main.ts

Comment: Please provide reproduction

Comment: Maybe you will find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting a similar error for unit testing. Turns out I was importing beforeEach from the wrong place:

```
import {beforeEach} from "selenium-webdriver/testing";
```

As soon as I removed this error was gone.