# ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir lazy. Module not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli, aot

I have a horrible problem with AOT build my app. In development mode everything's fine. But when i try build my app i got error:

```
ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir lazy
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts' in 'C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir'
resolve 'C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts' in 'C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir'
  using description file: C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir)
    using description file: C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/view-auth/auth.module.ngfactory.ts)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
[C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts]
[C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts.ts]
[C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts.js]
[C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-auth\auth.module.ngfactory.ts]
 @ ./src/$$_gendir lazy
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir lazy
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts' in 'C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir'
resolve 'C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts' in 'C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir'
  using description file: C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir)
    using description file: C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/view-ewniosek/ewniosek-views/ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
[C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts]
[C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts.ts]
[C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts.js]
[C:\Users\jarkro\IdeaProjects\vlo-frontend\src\$$_gendir\app\view-ewniosek\ewniosek-views\ewniosek.module.ngfactory.ts]
 @ ./src/$$_gendir lazy
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I was trying install `enhanced-resolve@3.3.0` but it still does not work.

Below version of libraries used in my app/

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.1
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.5
@angular/tsc-wrapped: 4.4.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.35
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.41
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.10
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.10
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Anyone had similar error and can help me?

Comment: Have you checked the error message: "Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration"?

Comment: This will solve your problem, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to incorrect path you are referencing.Please check path of module you are importing once again.