# Webpack 4 build with Angular 7 gives problem with the sass-loader when trying to access to node_modules

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-4, sass-loader

I was working on a upgrade from Angular v4 to v7. There are some breaking changes due to the .angular-cli.json to angular.json and their structure. And then also upgrading the versions of angular and webpack has its impact.

In Angular 4 it has worked fine with the custom webpack builder but upgrading to v7 has its complications. It is also worth mentioning that trying the build without any `@imports` in the scss on the node_modules that I use does work as expected too. So I see that the issue comes with the path to/from the webpack.

The main issue we have right now is that the sass-loader is compaining about the `@import 'path/to/file'` that it doesn't find it and then fails the build.

Doing `ng serve` and `ng build` does work without any problem, but doing the build with the custom webpack it does fail because it doesn't find the path.

The error I get is:

> ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>   @import '../../styles/src/abstracts/_mixins.scss";
>       ^
>            File to import not found or unreadable: '../../styles/src/abstracts/_mixins.scss";
>      Parent style sheet: stdin
>            in /Path/to/project (line 4, column 1)

I have also tried doing `npm link` from the package from my local machine to the node_modules without any progress.

The packages are components that I import in my projects, it is only packages with components and its scss.

The webpack config files looks like this:

*** webpack.config.app.prod.js ***

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var prod = require('./webpack.config.prod');
var AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;

module.exports = webpackMerge.strategy({
    plugins: 'prepend'
})(prod.config, {
    entry: './src/main-wp.editor.aot.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'editor.bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
        library: '_' + 'child',
        libraryTarget: 'jsonp'
    },
    plugins: [
        new AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.aot.json',
            entryModule: './src/app/modules/app.module#EditorModule',
            debug: true
        })
    ]
});
```

*** webpack.config.prod.js ***

```
var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');
var UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-3-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    config: webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: ['@ngtools/webpack']
                },

                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    warnings: false,
                    ie8: false,
                    output: {
                        comments: false
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    }),
    buildPath: function root(args) {
        var _root = path.resolve(__dirname);
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
    }
};
```

*** webpack.config.common.js ***

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var glob = require("glob");
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loaders: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "to-string-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader", // compiles Sass to CSS
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            includePaths: glob.sync(
                                path.join(__dirname, '**/node_modules/@mypackage/styles/src/abstracts')
                              ).map((dir) => path.dirname(dir)),
                            // includePaths: [path.resolve("node_modules/@mypackage")],
                            // includePaths: [
                            //     path.resolve('../node_modules')
                            // ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    },
    plugins: [

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

Versions I use for this.
"@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.15"
"uglifyjs-3-webpack-plugin": "1.2.4"
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "7.4.3"
"@ngtools/webpack": "7.0.7",
"@types/node": "8.9.5"
"node-sass": "4.5.3"
"sass-loader": "7.3.1"
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5"
"ts-node": "7.0.1"
"typescript": "3.2.4"
"webpack": "4.29.0"
"webpack-cli": "3.3.10"
"webpack-merge": "4.2.2"
And node 8.9.5 with npm 5.5.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it with `sass-loader` applying the following rule for `scss` the  `webpack.config.common.js` :

```
            {
                test: /\.component\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    'to-string-loader',                  
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                importer: url => {
                                    if (url.startsWith('@angular/')) {
                                        return {
                                            file: path.resolve(`./node_modules/${url}`),
                                        };
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                },
                            },
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

If you have another library in `node_module` that you need to use you can add another `else if` statement:

Example, let's say I have a custom library `my-library` in `node_modules` and I want to access to: `node_modules/my-library/style.scss` so I have to add the following `else if` statement:

```
       {
            test: /\.component\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
            use: [
                'to-string-loader',                  
                'css-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sassOptions: {
                            importer: url => {
                                if (url.startsWith('@angular/')) {
                                    return {
                                        file: path.resolve(`./node_modules/${url}`),
                                };
                                else if (url.startsWith('my-library/')) {
                                        return {
                                            file: path.resolve(`./node_modules/${url}`),
                                        };
                                    }
                                return null;
                            },
                        },
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Take in count that this was my project structure:

```
node_modules
dist
config
  - webpack.common.js
  - webpack.dev.js
  - webpack.prod.js
  - webpack.test.js
src
  - app
    - app-routing.module.ts
    - app.component.html
    - app.component.scss
    - app.component.ts
    - app.module.ts
    - index.ts
  - index.html
  - main.browser.ts
  - polyfills.browser.ts
angular.json
package.json
postcss.config.js
tsconfig.json
tsconfig.webpack.json
webpack.config.js
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi @gquinteros93! I liked the sassOptions you have but it didnt work for me. 
If it is worth mentioning, before this error I mentioned here I got this other error that I solved by doing `npm link` in my local package and `npm link packageName` on project folder. In that way I got rid of that first problem (see last comment on this link. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration])  I dont know if it has something to do with that? 

I have tried all possible solutions without any good solution. Thanks for the help!