# Multiple Angular libs do not work in production mode

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I've created an Angular project which consists of two Angular libs. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/agilie/angular-helpies). After that, I've built eaсh library and share the resulting `dist` folder via npm. Here is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agilie/angular-helpies.

After that, I'm trying to use the interceptor from this library and import it like this

```
import {DuplicateRequestFilter} from '@agilie/angular-helpies/interceptors';
```

Everything works correctly in dev mode however when I try to build project in production mode I get an error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'interceptors' in '/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/src/app'
resolve 'interceptors' in '/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/src/app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/
        using description file: /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/package.json (relative path: .)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/package.json (relative path: ./interceptors)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors.tsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors doesn't exist
      /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/src/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/sergey/libs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/sergey/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/interceptors)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors.tsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors doesn't exist
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors.ts]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors.tsx]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors.mjs]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/interceptors.js]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/src/app/node_modules]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/src/node_modules]
[/Users/sergey/libs/node_modules]
[/Users/sergey/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors.ts]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors.tsx]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors.mjs]
[/Users/sergey/libs/test-helpies/node_modules/interceptors.js]
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 14:0-35 15:1945-1970
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

You can reproduce the error using this demo project: https://github.com/SergeyMell/test-helpies

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

#### Update

Answers in [Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration) seem to provide solutions how to fix actually broken package in consuming app. In my case as I understand I have some issues in building or distributing my package so this should be fixed.

Comment: any documentation for this plugin?

Comment: checked what i have added below?

Comment: The plugin is on the early development stage so I didn't provide any documentation for now unfortunatelly. However, the usage is pretty straightforward - import interceptor from `@agilie/angular-helpies/interceptors` and use it among providers.

Comment: added something below. check that out?

Comment: i used ur library here:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aokp5u. No Error in this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration)

Comment: Stackblitz does not compile code in production mode. I also don't have any issues in development mode, only in production.
Regarding ur link - let me check. I've read many of similar ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to overcome the issue. The problem was in package namings. As long as my root package is names as `@agilie/angular-helpies` the children packages should be named as `@agilie/angular-helpies/interceptors` and `@agilie/angular-helpies/decorators` but not simply `interceptors` or `decorators`.

This looks very strange because if I try to generate the lib with such name I get an error `Project name "@agilie/angular-helpies/<some name here>" is invalid`. Also when I rename the packages manually I get a warning that `String violates the pattern`. However, it works.

Possibly this could be fixed in some other manner (npm links or smth different) but I found this one solution. Actually Angular has similar namings if you check https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/package.json for example

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to /interceptors in your import.

Also you are not having public-api.ts in interceptors folder

Have a reference here where your public-api.ts should be and how to export your classes properly. Like @angular/common/http have exported.

https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/common/http

Comment: There is no need to add an interceptor into the module.

Comment: ok, I tried but this didn't help. Neither using as it was before nor including whole `InterceptorsModule` into my application. The error remain the same. Actually interceptors are not required to be a part of a module so this suggestion seem to be the wrong way.

Comment: Stackblitz does not compile code in production mode. I also don't have any issues in development mode, only in production. Regarding ur link - let me check. I've read many similar ones

Comment: what angular version you are using?

Comment: 8.2.14 in both (library and consuming projects)

Comment: This looks like smth making sense. Let me check

Comment: if its works please vote, took lots of efforts to figure out. had to go through your library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214744/discussion-between-sergey-mell-and-aakash-garg).