# How to solve production build issue of

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, encryption, angular8

I have created my Angular 8 application.
on command **ng serve** application running smoothly without any errors and code work properly but,
when I create a build for production then I got the error image shown below.

I use the **node-rsa** package to encrypted and decrypt my data but I'm not able to build a project for a production server, I don't know how these errors are raised.

My **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cftrack",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.4",
    "angular-animations": "^0.11.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.18",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "node-rsa": "^1.1.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeng": "^11.0.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.66",
    "@types/node-rsa": "^1.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.4"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 8.3.29.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "author": "Sachin",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My **angular.json** file

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "CFTRACK": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {},
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/CFTRACK",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": false,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/files",
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/web.config"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/v4-shims.min.css",
                            "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css",
                            "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
                            "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                                    "maximumError": "10mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "10kb",
                                    "maximumError": "15kb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "CFTRACK:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "CFTRACK:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "CFTRACK:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/files",
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/web.config"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "CFTRACK:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "CFTRACK:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "CFTRACK"
}
```

After I enter the command "**ng build --prod**"
it raised error after 92% done like this

[image]

Comment: try deleting your node_modules and run npm i. It seems that angular doesn't find the nodemodules for node-rsa.

Answer (score 0):

You mention

> I have created my Angular 10 application

But package.json shows an angular 8 application ???

The first line of errors is: `node-modules doesn't exist`

Are You sure npm packages installed successfully?

Check it with npm install again.

Set aot flag in angular.json to true, to enable a head of time compilation.

serve the application again, you must see the problem.

For

```
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

error see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration)

Comment: Sorry Sir, by mistake I write 10 instead of 8. This is an Angular 8 application

Comment: I deleted 2 times **node-modules** and again installed it but still, the same error occurs

Comment: Add your angular.json file?

Comment: I have added my **angular.json** file

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to these related issues/bugs/errors,

by adding in **package.json**

```
"browser": {
        "path": false,
        "stream": false,
        "tls": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "constants": false
    }
```

more detail visit below mention almost the same error answer link https://stackoverflow.com/a/52367183/12213901