# Adding free disk space metrics to AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Could anyone explain the following based on this article on how to add disk space metrics to AWs CloudWatch by @VolkanPaksoy: https://volkanpaksoy.com/archive/2018/12/19/Monitoring-EC2-Instance-Disk-Space-with-AWS-CloudWatch/

Step 5: The UI has changed since the posting. Could anyone explain this step in more details, using the latest UI?

Step 6: Can this step be done using the AWS Management site? Or does it require logging in to the actual EC2?

And, regarding logs: can logs stored in %PROGRAMDATA%\Amazon\SSM\Logs\ be deleted without any issues? Is there any other place AWS logs are stored? I think they are eating up ALOT of my disk space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudWatch Agent for Windows already included Free Disk Space monitoring.

Please follow the guide on running the Wizard from this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html

Comment: I'm on an autoscaling system, can't install the agent every time it scales my system can I? Looking for something more "automatic".

Comment: if you are using autoscaling, create your own custom AMI configured with the config file at ProgramData\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json . Run the Wizard one time in an instance, and export this instance as your custom AMI. use this AMI in your autoscaling configuration. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html#creating-an-ami