# Importing anything from @angular/cdk in Cypress tests breaks the build with Angular 13

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-package-format

Since updating to Angular 13, my Cypress tests that are importing from @angular/cdk (mostly for using test harnesses on Angular material) fail to compile with the following error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/platform.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in 'C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\fesm2015'
resolve '@angular/common' in 'C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\fesm2015'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\package.json (relative path: ./fesm2015)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\fesm2015\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\dev\workspace\exp\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules
        using description file: C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules
        using description file: C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in C:\dev\node_modules
        No description file found
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in C:\dev\workspace\node_modules
        No description file found
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common is not a file
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@angular/common)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        No description file found
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.json doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        No description file found
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.jsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.json doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.js doesn't exist
        .json
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.mjs doesn't exist
            .coffee
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.jsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.js doesn't exist
        .json
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.json doesn't exist
        .jsx
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.coffee doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.mjs doesn't exist
            .coffee
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.json doesn't exist
        .jsx
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.jsx doesn't exist
        .mjs
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.coffee doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.jsx doesn't exist
        .mjs
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.mjs doesn't exist
        .coffee
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.tsx doesn't exist
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.mjs doesn't exist
        .coffee
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.coffee doesn't exist
        .ts
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.tsx doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index
                  using description file: C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.coffee doesn't exist
        .ts
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.ts doesn't exist
        .tsx
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            as directory
              C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common doesn't exist
                      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.ts doesn't exist
        .tsx
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.tsx doesn't exist
        as directory
          C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common doesn't exist
                      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.js doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.tsx doesn't exist
        as directory
          C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common doesn't exist
                      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.json doesn't exist
                    .jsx
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.jsx doesn't exist
                    .mjs
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.mjs doesn't exist
                    .coffee
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.coffee doesn't exist
                    .ts
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.ts doesn't exist
                    .tsx
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.tsx doesn't exist
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\fesm2015\node_modules]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\node_modules]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\node_modules]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\dev\node_modules\package.json]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\package.json]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.js]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common\package.json]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.json]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.js]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common\package.json]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.jsx]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.json]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.js]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.mjs]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.jsx]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.js]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.json]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.coffee]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.mjs]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.json]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.jsx]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.ts]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.coffee]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.jsx]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.mjs]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common.tsx]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.ts]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.mjs]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.coffee]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\cdk\node_modules\@angular\common.tsx]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.coffee]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.ts]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.ts]
[C:\dev\node_modules\@angular\common.tsx]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.js]
[C:\dev\workspace\node_modules\@angular\common.tsx]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.json]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.jsx]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.mjs]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.coffee]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.ts]
[C:\dev\workspace\exp\cypress-test\node_modules\@angular\common\index.tsx]
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/platform.mjs 3:0-52 38:14-31
 @ ./cypress/integration/spec.ts
```

Any idea how to solve this? I assume it has something to do with the changes in the Angular Package Format..

See this repo for reproducing the issue: https://github.com/pongells/angular13-cypress

Comment: Maybe related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration)?

Comment: please put your `tsconfig.ts` too.

Comment: Is it reproducable on a clean newly created Angular 13 project? Can you please create a small github repository that proves that?

Comment: Here is a repo: https://github.com/pongells/angular13-cypress just run the e2e tests to see the failure

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile, we found a workaround:

```
const webpackPreprocessor = require('@cypress/webpack-batteries-included-preprocessor')

module.exports = (on) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor({
    typescript: require.resolve('typescript')
  }))
}
```

see: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19066