# I'm using Main.tsx instead of Main.js and receive "Main.jsx doesn't exist"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I'm using Main.tsx instead of Main.js and receive "Main.jsx doesn't exist"
Do you know what can be the reason?

The Error I'm getting after running the **npm start** command:
[The Error I'm getting after running the **npm start** command:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrTyz.png)

[This is the **Main.tsx** file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6GFU.png)

[This is the **Index.tsx** file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHuRg.png)

[This is the **package.json** file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAF48.png)

Comment: Did you find this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration/43313089
You seem to have an invalid webpack configuration. How did you create your project? If you generated it using 'create-react-app', maybe try it with '--template typescript'?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code here.