# Display component by its selector or reference

Tags: angular, angular-components

container-component.ts

```
export class ContainerComponent{
    innerComponentRef; //We have this
    innerComponentSelector;//We have this
    }
```

However in container-component.html I don't know how to append html with innerComponent tag. String interpolation - doesn't work for sure. I also wonder if it's not a kinda bad practice what I want to make.

Comment: are you on about custom components?

Comment: Yes, created by me.

Comment: This isn't how the framework works. Component metadata isn't available to a developer. You will need to maintain a map of components in order to match them by selector or other string, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40063568/3731501 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48825228/3731501

Answer (score -1):

If you register the components within the `declarations: []` in the NgModule, you can do the following in the container-component.html:

```
<div>
    <innerComponentRef></innerComponentRef>
    <innerComponentSelector></innerComponentSelector>
</div>
```

Changing `innerComponentRef` and `innerComponentSelector` for the `selector: ""` names

Comment: Consider innerComponentRef and innerComponentSelector as variables known only in typescript. InnerComponentSelector can be 'app-inner-1' or 'app-inner-2' or whatever else. That's the problem. I also was wondering about some *ngFor looping all defined components and taking only this one which selector==innerComponentSelector.