# Factorize functions names in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, factorization

I do not know if it's possible but I would factorize functions like

```js
  // wiki
  if(command === "wiki"){
    bangSearch('wikiSearch','_',args);
  }

  // afr amazon fr
  if(command === ("afr")){
    bangSearch('amazonSearch','+',args);
  }

  function wikiSearch(recherche){
    var url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+recherche+"&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json";
    request(url, function(err, resopnse, json){
      //some code
    });
  }

  function amazonSearch(recherche){
    var url = "https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="+recherche;
    message.channel.send('Recherche amazon pour: '+recherche+'\n'+url);
  }

  function bangSearch(searchFunctionName,keywordSeparator,args){

    if(args.length > 1){
      searchFunctionName(args.join(keywordSeparator));
    }else if (args.length == 0) {
      searchFunctionName(/*some args*/);
    }else{
      searchFunctionName(args[0]);
    }
  }
```

But when i run the code, I have this error:
TypeError: searchFunctionName is not a function

So, I understand that the code does not call searchFunctionName like wikiSearch or amazonSearch but it only understands that the called function is searchFunctionName.

So I can not call the argument function which is either "wikiSearch" or "amazonSearch"

Is it possible to do this? Can you help me ?

The entire code:
Here is the entire code. It's for a discord bot and i use Discord.js

```js
 // wiki
  if(command === "wiki"){
    console.log(args);
    bangSearch(wikiSearch,'_',args);
  }

  // afr amazon fr
  if(command === ("afr")){
    bangSearch(amazonSearch,'+',args);
  }


  function wikiSearch(recherche){
    var url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+recherche+"&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json";
    request(url, function(err, resopnse, json){
      try {
        var name = JSON.parse(json)[1];
        var link = JSON.parse(json)[3];
        if(name ==='undefined'){
          message.channel.send('Aucun résultats');
        }else {
          message.channel.send('Recherche wikipedia pour: '+recherche);
          message.channel.send('Nom: '+name[0]+'\n'+link[0]+'\n\n');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        callback('ERREUR: '+e);
      }
    });
  }

  function amazonSearch(recherche){
    var url = "https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="+recherche;
    message.channel.send('Recherche amazon pour: '+recherche+'\n'+url);
  }

  function bangSearch(searchFunctionName,keywordSeparator,args){

    if(args.length > 1){
      searchFunctionName(args.join(keywordSeparator));
    }else if (args.length == 0) {
      message.channel.send('tu veux quoi ?').then(() => {
        message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content.length > 0 , {
          max: 1,
          time: 10000,
          errors: ['time'],
        }).then((collected) => {
          searchFunctionName(collected.first().content);
        }).catch(() => {
          message.channel.send('T\'as pas trouvé les touches sur ton clavier ou quoi ?');
        });
      });
    }else{
      searchFunctionName(args[0]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript - It's not really a nice way to do this. Instead use an object.

Comment: just pass the function name, not a string.

Comment: @DavinTryon that would circumvent using eval. phew

Comment: @DavinTryon, I assume you mean a reference to the function. The function name IS a string, and it is exactly what he is passing right now.

Comment: @espacarello yes, but no! `bangSearch(amazonSearch)` would be much better

Comment: How about an explicit mapping: `const searchFunctions = {afr: amazonSearch, wiki: wikiSearch}; searchFunctions["afr"]("bla");`

Comment: @espacarello I don't think that is the correct duplicate.  In this case, the OP has the function, not just its name as a string.  better to pass the function (by reference) directly.

Comment: @davin thats why i voted to reopen ( i love democracy ;)), so would you mind adding that as an answer?

Comment: @BarbeBleue, what are you trying to build here? What is the purpose of `bangSearch()`? At the moment, `bangSearch('wikiSearch','_',args)` is just a complicated way to do `wikiSearch(args.join("_"))`. So why would you want to use it? How do you think you benefit from this construct?

Comment: @Thomas, because i would like to use the same code in bangSearch, when i use wikiSearch OR amazonSearch

Comment: @DavinTryon I must have made a mistake somewhere but actually passed the name of the function without the quotes, works
thank you !

Comment: @barbebleue by the way `searchFunctionName(args.join(seperator))` works in every case ( 0 or 1 element)...

Comment: @BarbeBleue I don't understand, all the code in `bangSearch` is merely a Array#join and the conditions are pointless. you can reduce it to `function bangSearch(searchFunction,keywordSeparator,args){ searchFunction(args.join(keywordSeparator)); }` and call `bangSearch(wikiSearch, '_', args)` or you simply call `wikiSearch(args.join('_'))`. To me, bangSearch just complicates the code without real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function `keywordSearch` to compose a function that can correctly handle keywords:

```
// aka bangSearch
const keywordSearch = (searchFn) => 
  (...keywords) => keywords.length ? 
    searchFn(...keywords) :
      // your complicated logic...;
```

Use the `keywordSearch` function to compose your keyword search functions:

```
const wikipediaUrl = (keywords) => `https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=${keywords.join('_')}&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json`;
const wikipedia = keywordSearch((...keywords) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>         
    request(wikipediaUrl(keywords), (err, response) => 
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(response));

const amazonUrl = (keywords) => `https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=${keywords.join('+')}`;
const amazon = keywordSearch((...keywords) => 
  message.channel.send(`Recherche amazon pour:${keywords.join(',')} \n ${amazonUrl(keywords)}`);
```

Expose the keyword search functions on an object:

```
const providers = { wikipedia, amazon, };
```

Or if you are using ES6 modules you can use the module syntax to be clever:

```
// search-providers.js
export * as wikpedia from './wikipedia';
export * amazon from './amazon';
```

Then use the search provider.

`['wikipedia']` uses the indexer syntax for retrieving the value of an object property:

```
import * as providers from './search-providers'; // if you are using modules
const runTheSearch = async () => {
  // ...
  const result = await providers['wikipedia']('this is my search'); // assuming everything is promisified 
}
```

Comment: You should at least explain what you are doing here. ES6 might not be understandable for a 6rep OP

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript is functional, you can pass functions (by reference) to another function!  So, with the least amount of changes, this should work for you:

```
// wiki
  if(command === "wiki"){
    bangSearch(wikiSearch,'_',args);
  }

  // afr amazon fr
  if(command === ("afr"){
    bangSearch(amazonSearch,'+',args);
  }

  function wikiSearch(recherche){
    var url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+recherche+"&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json";
    request(url, function(err, resopnse, json){
      //some code
    });
  }

  function amazonSearch(recherche){
    var url = "https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="+recherche;
    message.channel.send('Recherche amazon pour: '+recherche+'\n'+url);
  }

  function bangSearch(searchFunctionName,keywordSeparator,args){

    if(args.length > 1){
      searchFunctionName(args.join(keywordSeparator));
    }else if (args.length == 0) {
      searchFunctionName(/*some args*/);
    }else{
      searchFunctionName(args[0]);
    }
  }
```

This takes advantage of function hoisting so the `amazonSearch` and `wikiSearch` functions do not have to be defined above where their references are used.  However, for readability, you might want to define them above the usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map of your search functions which then you can access using the keys. Yet another solution. Also it will be nicer if you pass in the `searchFunctions` also as an argument rather than keeping it as a side-effect.

If there is only one item in array, `join` will in effect return the first item as a string so, you only need two conditions there.

```
['something'].join('+'); // "something"
```

```js
// wiki
var command = "wiki";
var args = [1, 2, 3];

var searchFunctions = {
  wikiSearch: function(recherche) {
    console.log(recherche)
  },
  amazonSearch: function(recherche) {
    console.log(recherche)
    }
}

switch (command) {
  case 'wiki':
    bangSearch('wikiSearch', '_', args);
    break;
  case 'amazon':
    bangSearch('amazonSearch', '+', args);
    break;
}

function bangSearch(searchFunctionName, keywordSeparator, args) {
  if (args.length) {
    searchFunctions[searchFunctionName](args.join(keywordSeparator));
  } else {
    searchFunctions[searchFunctionName]( /*some args*/ );
  }
}
```