# Type declaration for function that returns a class constructor

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, constructor, declaration

I'm writing a TypeScript declaration file for a JavaScript game engine with a global structure and I don't quite know how to deal with this function that returns a class constructor. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
var createScript = function(name) {
  var script = function(args) {
    this.app = args.app;
    this.entity = args.entity;
  }
  script._name = name

  return script;
}
```

Users are meant to extend the `script` class constructor with their own code like this:

```
var MyScript = createScript('myScript');

MyScript.someVar = 6;

MyScript.prototype.update = function(dt) {
  // Game programming stuff
}
```

What is the proper way to deal with the `createScript` function and `script` class constructor in my declaration file?

**UPDATE**
I have updated my code example to show that users are also expected to extend the static side of the "class". The answers given so far, though awesome, don't seem to allow for that.

Comment: Side note: the `name` property of a function is read-only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: @RobertPenner you are absolutely right. My mistake, I'll edit the code.

Comment: If you absolutely need the function name to be dynamic, you could use `eval` or `new Function`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, one possible way to represent a class constructor is by using an interface with so-called [constructor signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes). Because `createScript` is supposed to return an instance of user-created (or, more precisely, user-modified) class, it has to be generic. The user will have to provide an interface that describes extended class as generic paratemeter for `createScript`:

```
export interface ScriptConstructorArgs {
    app: {};     // dummy empty type declarations here
    entity: {}; 
}
export interface Script {  // decsribes base class
    app: {};
    entity: {};
}

export interface ScriptConstructor<S extends Script> {
    _name: string;
    new(args: ScriptConstructorArgs): S;
}

// type declaration for createScript
declare var createScript: <S extends Script>(name: string) => ScriptConstructor<S>;
```

When using `createScript`, users must describe extended class and separately provide its implementation by assigning to the prototype

```
interface MyScript extends Script {
    update(dt: {}): void;
}
var MyScript = createScript<MyScript>('myScript');

MyScript.prototype.update = function(dt) {
  // Game programming stuff
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want users to be able to extend constructor type too (to customize  "static" side of the class), you can do that with some extra work. It involves adding another generic parameter for customized constructor type. Users also have to provide an interface describing that type - `MyScriptClass` in this example:

```
export interface ScriptConstructorArgs {
    app: {};     // dummy empty type declarations here
    entity: {}; 
}
export interface Script {  // decsribes base class
    app: {};
    entity: {};
}

export interface ScriptConstructor<S extends Script> {
    _name: string;
    new(args: ScriptConstructorArgs): S;
}

// type declaration for createScript
declare var createScript: <Instance extends Script, 
                           Class extends ScriptConstructor<Instance>
                        >(name: string) => Class;

interface MyScript extends Script {
    update(dt: {}): void;
}
interface MyScriptClass extends ScriptConstructor<MyScript> {
    someVar: number;
}
var MyScript = createScript<MyScript, MyScriptClass>('myScript');

MyScript.prototype.update = function(dt) {
  // Game programming stuff
}

MyScript.someVar = 6;
```

Just be aware that in this solution the compiler does not really check that 
provided implementation conforms to the declared interface - you can assign anything to `prototype.update` and compiler will not complain. Also, until `prototype.update` and `someVar` are assigned, you get undefined when you try to use them, and compiler will not catch that too.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

The reason why the assignment to `prototype.udpate` is not typechecked is that somehow the static part of `MyScript` is inferred to be a `Function`, and `Function.prototype` is declared in the [built-in library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L288) as `any`,  which suppresses type checking. There is an easy fix: just declare your own, more specific `prototype`:

```
export interface ScriptConstructor<S extends Script> {
    _name: string;
    new(args: ScriptConstructorArgs): S;
    prototype: S;
}
```

then it starts catching errors like this:

```
MyScript.prototype.udpate = function(dt) {
  // Game programming stuff
}
// Property 'udpate' does not exist on type 'MyScript'. Did you mean 'update'?
```

Also, `dt` parameter type is also inferred from the `MyScript` interface.

Actually I don't have much experience doing stuff like this, so I don't know if declaring your own prototype could cause some problems with other code in the future.

Also, it will not complain if the assignment to `prototype.update` is missing altogether - it will still believe `update` is there because it was declared in `createScript` type. That's the price to pay for "assembling" a class from javascript implementation together with some external type declarations - the "normal", all-typescript way to create a class is just use something like `class MyScript extends ScriptBase implements SomeInterface`, then it's guaranteed to be typechecked.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I'm curious though, why won't the compiler check that the implementation conforms to the declared interface?

Comment: This works as well as can be expected, thank you. I was thinking, we have two interfaces, one for the instance side, one for the static(constructor) side of the class. Would it be possible to write a proper TypeScript class that would implement both of these instances?

Comment: It would look like this: `class S {    a(): void { }    static b: number; }` You can refer to static side as `typeof S`. However there is no way to declare that static side must conform to some interface AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

you can declare the returntype of `createScript` as some kind of generic script constructor

```
interface AbstractScript { 
    app;
    entity;
}

interface ScriptConstructor<T extends AbstractScript> { 
    new(args: AbstractScript): T;
    readonly prototype: T;
}

declare function createScript(name: string): ScriptConstructor<any>;
```

and then

```
interface Foo extends AbstractScript { 
    foo(): void;
}

let Foo:ScriptConstructor<Foo> = createScript("Foo");
Foo.prototype.foo = function () { }

let d = new Foo({app: "foo", entity: "bar"});
d.foo();
d.entity
d.app
```

Note: named the constructor and the interface of the created class both `Foo` for conveniance reasons. 

Thaught first, TS might have an issue with that, but no, it differentiates nicely.

Comment: Typings are good. Some typos: `ScriptConsturctor` and `: String` should be lowercase.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous wording but I thought the typo in `ScriptConsturctor` was obvious ("u" and "r" swapped).