# Naming a dynamically created javascript type

Tags: javascript, prototype, anonymous-types

I'm trying to create a function `Vector` that takes a number `n` and returns a type `Vector[n]`:

```
let Vector = n => {
    const result = function(...vals) {
        this._data = Array(n).fill(0).map((_, i) => vals[i] || 0)
        Object.assign(this, this._data.reduce((a, c, i) => ({ ...a, ['v' + i]: c }), {}));
    }
    result.prototype.add = function(v) {
        return new result(...this._data.map((x, i) => x + v._data[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And it works just fine:

```
 let Vec2 = Vector(2);
 let v1 = new Vec2(0, 1);
 let v2 = v1.add(new Vec2(1, 2))
 console.log(v2);
```

The logged value looks like this:

```
 result {_data: Array(2), v0: 1, v1: 3}
```

It's all working as intended, except that the name of the type is 'result'. I'd rather name it 'Vector2' in this case. How could I do this?

I tried to to create a dynamic name by replacing `result` with `this['Vector' + n]` but that resulted in this:

```
 Vector.(anonymous function) {_data: Array(2), v0: 1, v1: 3}
```

I also tried assigning `result.name` and `result.prototype.name` but neither worked as intended.

**Is it possible to rename a dynamically created type in Javascript?**

Comment: Why do you need to rename a type? Are you going to reuse it further in the code?

Comment: Firefox doesn't even log the name; everything's just "Object".

Comment: I tried making a dummy object with a computed property name, hoping Chrome would associate the name with the constructor, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I suspect the only answer is to use `new Function()` and pass in the function body with the required name.

Comment: `const result = { ["Vector" + n]: (...args) { /* your code */ } }["Vector" + n];` should work as mentioned in the dupe.

Comment: @lolbas mostly for debugging reasons, and yes that's the purpose of the function, to create a type that I can use in the code. @ Pointy I apologize but I should've mentioned- I'm using Chrome. Should I edit the question with these details or do I leave it as is since it's duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Using `new Function()` or `eval()` and enclosing your logic in a template string works.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript) for more information on dynamic function names.

```js
let Vector = n => {
  const name = 'Vec' + n;
  return new Function(`return function ${name}(...vals) {
    this._data = Array(${n}).fill(0).map((_, i) => vals[i] || 0)
    Object.assign(this, this._data.reduce((a, c, i) => ({ ...a, ['v' + i]: c }), {}));
    this.add = function(v) {
      return new ${name}(...this._data.map((x, i) => x + v._data[i]));
    }
  }`)()
}

const Vec2 = Vector(2);
const Vec3 = Vector(3);

const vec2 = new Vec2(0, 1);
const vec3 = new Vec3(0, 1, 2);

console.log(vec2 instanceof Vec2);
console.log(vec3 instanceof Vec3);
console.log(Vec2.name, Vec3.name);
console.log(vec2.add(new Vec2(1, 2)));
console.log(vec3.add(new Vec3(1, 2, 3)));
```

Comment: I may have mentioned using `Function`, but I don't endorse it...

Comment: Sorry for this, I updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Your `Vector` function returns a anonymous function.
If you git it a name, that name will be used by Chrome devtools.

Each environment treats this differently.
Consider the following snippet:

```js
const test = function OldName(){}
Object.defineProperty(test, 'name', {value: 'NewName'})
 
console.log(new test())
```

Chrome logs 'OldName':
[image]

Firefox logs 'Object':
[image]

Node.js logs 'NewName':
[image]

One possible solution is use the `Function` constructor (`new Function()`):

```js
const vector = n => new Function(`return function Vector${n}(){}`)()
const test = vector(3)

console.log(new test())
```

This logs correctly in Chrome.

Comment: and how precisely do you give it a (dynamic) name?

Comment: I don't think it is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript
I tried to set the name with `Object.definePropety()` but Chrome still uses the old name.

Comment: Well, you can use `eval()` or `new Function()`, but that throws performance, security and readability through the window....