# Dynamic constructor name in js

Tags: javascript, constructor

I want to do exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript) but use the function as a constructor.

```
> function nameFunction(name, body) {
   return {[name](...args) {return body(...args)}}[name]
}

> b = nameFunction('c', function () {})
[Function: c]
> typeof b
'function'
```

`b` is a function, yet it is not a constructor:

```
> new b()
Uncaught TypeError: b is not a constructor
```

If done in the standard way, it is a constructor:

```
> b = function() {}
[Function: b]
> new b()
b {}
```

But the name is b, not c.

How can I build a constructor with the given name and not using eval?

Comment: `nameFunction` returns an object, not a function? If you would like to use `new` it should return a class or a "regular" function (not an arrow function).

Comment: @evolutionxbox how is b in the code given an arrow function? How do you show that it is an object? `typeof b === 'function'`

Comment: You're right. It's not an arrow function (I didn't say it was). My recommendation is to return a class or regular function.

Comment: @evolutionxbox but I want the name of the created object to be dynamic

Comment: I couldn't really figure out why the function being returned wasn't a constructor function. It is most likely be due to the fact it's being made inside an object.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350988/989920) may be your best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66663515/783743) provided by [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) is correct but incomplete. In order to use the dynamically named function as a constructor, not only do you need to use an ordinary function but also you need to preserve the `this` context. We can do this by applying `this` and `arguments` to the `body` as follows.

```js
function nameFunction(name, body) {
    const object = {
        [name]: function () {
            return body.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };

    return object[name];
}

const Bar = nameFunction("Foo", function (foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
});

console.log(Bar.name, new Bar(42));
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods are not constructors (see https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-functioncreate and https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-functionallocate). Just define it as an ordinary function:

```
function nameFunction(name, body) {
   return {[name]: function(...args) {return body(...args)}}[name]
}

b = nameFunction('c', function () {})

new b
```

Comment: I'm not sure this entirely works? `b = nameFunction('c', function () { this.x = 'x' }); new b() // Object { } <- no x property`?