# How can I specify the type parameter in a constructor type?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I make a base class and write a factory function to derive some child classes at runtime. The factory function is generic as well. But I have difficulty typing instances of the derived class. Some typing information about type parameters are seemingly lost. I wonder whether typing this kind of derived objects accurately is possible in TypeScript.

For illustration, here is a generic binary tree class `BinaryTree<T, U, V>`, where `T` is the tag of a node:

```
/** @template T, U, V */
class BinaryTree {
  /** @type {T} */
  tag
  /**
   * @param {U} left
   * @param {V} right
   */
  constructor(left, right) {
    this.left = left
    this.right = right
  }
}
```

And I can derive a class for leaf nodes.

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @extends BinaryTree<T, null, null> */
class Leaf extends BinaryTree {
  tag = 'leaf'
  constructor() { super(null, null) }
}
```

Now for the factory function:

```
/**
 * @template {string} T
 * @template {BinaryTree<string, any, any>} U
 * @template {BinaryTree<string, any, any>} V
 * @param {T} tag
 * @returns {new <U, V>(l:U, r:V) => BinaryTree<tag,U,V>}
 */
function makeBinaryTreeClass(tag) {
  return { [tag]: 
    /**
     * @template U, V 
     * @extends BinaryTree<tag, U, V> */
    class extends BinaryTree {
      tag = tag
    } }[tag]
}
*/
```

Now I can derive a tree node class of some tag:

```
const TaggedTreeNode = makeBinaryTreeClass('tag')

const node1 = new TaggedTreeNode(new Leaf(), new Leaf())
```

So far so good: `node1` has the type `BinaryTree<'tag', Leaf<any>, Leaf<any>>`. Note that the resulting type is not `Leaf<'tag'>`, because the `U`, `V` are redeclared inside the return statement.

How to annotate the type for an instance of `TaggedTreeNode`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/FAegVGAEACAuCmBbADgGwIYMgFQDSQFV8A1SMEYAYwwGcbIAhASwDt0AnAT23fnkgDewSJHBQ4nZPwHYAvmQojY6AObDREdWRjIO6RIILzU8AGawt43e32Di89kxUALCyIXrKAexY1Y7AFdKWC92AAoTc3xHF1gASkEtSFhnJhoAOkjYSABeSCyklLT0mNdcyFK3SFlgGtBNbTgkNEx+bGFxeAAPBBYAE3pmNi4ePgAePEgWANRUfGnZgD4PanQ6SAAZeHRTSG7egcZWDm5eaU8fP0Dg0LCEgUgaAKlwhbmpmdQEmrqxDpgECgMFgBFdWCp5O1GoCWiChidRvAxmCWCp8OgWJx0ZjFvICP8mkDWoJ4SMzsj-ODsVjIBjOLjIMQCdZbDJ5Mo1I1eLAAuxfIIWPAAO6QMZERmLCIALnF7ClxASOWWpNO4w5uCIxFxHQopgCLGCTB8kEQ6AA1vAVYiAMK0GhhDn3dTc3ksQSQADaHIAulLIEk-u4ROIYcD+OLSElGvt4P1BscyWrVPgI8tyElVusY3GjsNVecg0pVOUOUl5LIvapvbVgFRLtlsKoVPA+oiAHJePr8PKmi1Ws62tb2gDkHOHcVr3l82RYnfgAEZyoKRY2VM3W2cO12wsvNttTHd5sK9zs7hPQCBIAAFdheABGJkQfoAEl4RSFkpJ+Oh8mlsl5dgAA1Xdd2znQCaAAflrEBLwAMXQJgTD6WlYBhWAAG5IEAgBJacMUoeBsC-QCTXNeB6FYUxQlNWAjTddA7y8AJsmbQVHEoehUC8PwsJSeBOEgO94G8RB+AAIn1M1ZyFFhxJgiAAS-QQAEF2BsTgxjwvwCKIr8JibFswK7RYGXTKc-FpdT0E4AB5UwQKMzc53oPIPVnLt52rYAOA0+zHI3Pgtwoj0AAZvUyMxslES9YGUtJIEklhpLfOSAEJ-SAA)

The best I could do is using `InstanceType<...>` to retrieve the return type of a constructor, but I did not find a way to make the compiler refine the types of the child nodes; they became "unknown".

For example,

```
/** @type {Array<InstanceType<TaggedTreeNode>>} */
const arrayOfTaggedTreeNodes = [node1]

// arrayOfTaggedTreeNodes has type `BinaryTree<"tag", unknown, unknown>[]`;
// expecting `BinaryTree<"tag", BinaryTree<string, any, any>, BinaryTree<string, any, any>>`.

arrayOfTaggedTreeNodes[0].left  // type is "unknown"!
```

Because the tags are meant to be supplied at runtime, hardcoding the type as `BinaryTree<"tag", ...>` is not what I want.

---

#### Edit

Because there was a requirement that the name of derived classes must be set dynamically, I had to use a trick `{[tag]: class {...}}[tag]`, [as this answer demonstrated (but for functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66663515/2281355). Sorry if that causes confusion.

Actually, if you do not annotate the return type (removing the `@returns {...}`), TypeScript infers it to `typeof [tag]`, which is more weird:

```
/**
 * @template {string} T
 * @param {T} tag
 */
function makeBinaryTreeClass(tag) {
  return { [tag]: 
    /**
     * @template U, V 
     * @extends BinaryTree<tag, U, V> */
    class extends BinaryTree {
      tag = tag
    } }[tag]
}

const TaggedTreeNode = makeBinaryTreeClass('tag')
// type inferred: `typeof [tag]`
```

Comment: I'm having trouble wading through your jsdoc here and converting to regular TS makes confuses me more. Why are you treating `tag` like a type parameter (e.g., `BinaryTree<tag, U, V>` instead of `BinaryTree<T, U, V>`)?  Why does `makeBinaryTreeClass` itself accept generics `U` and `V` if it doesn't use them (the returned constructor has its own `U` and `V`)?  Why does the implementation put the constructor into an object and then immediately index into that object to get the constructor out? What purpose does that serve? If these are necessary, why? If not, please [edit] so the code is a [mre].

Comment: Furthermore: it seems like you should just not annotate the variable if it is inferred as the type you want.  Or you can annotate it with that type yourself (e.g., `BinaryTree<'tag', Leaf<any>, Leaf<any>>`).  If I do either of those then `arrayOfTaggedNodes[0].left` is of type `Leaf<any>` (as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/weyQYw) with a TS version that hopefully fixes the issues in prev comment).  Is that what you want?  If not, could you edit to clarify the unmet need?

Comment: Sorry for the code looking awkward. I tried to simplify a very specific use case where the name of constructor mattered in consumer code. The `{name: ...}[name]` is actually setting the anonymous class's name to `name`, though not obviously. I will clarify.

Comment: If you don't need the anonymous class's name to be set for the purposes of this question, you should probably remove that instead of clarifying.  That is, the [mre] should ideally not distract us with issues unrelated to your problem.  Could you also address the other points I brought up?

Comment: Note: I didn't say *TypeScript* got confused by `{[k]: v}[k]`, I said *I* was confused by it.  And it's still confusing/distracting, even with the explanation.

Comment: The code is first written and the types are later annotated. My question is that, If the code is well-typed, then what type annotations are needed to convince TypeScript compiler, if possible? The change you proposed is valid, but that would change the behavior of my code, and thus breaking the use case it was simplified from.