# Naming functions in javascript object when dynamically adding functions to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

In our React project, we have an object of functions built like:

```
const eqs = {
    atr2FgmPg: (obj) => { return obj.atr2Fgm / obj.gp; },
    atr2FgaPg: (obj) => { return obj.atr2Fga / obj.gp; },
    atr2FgPct: (obj) => { return obj.atr2Fgm / obj.atr2Fga; },
    paint2FgmPg: (obj) => { return obj.paint2Fgm / obj.gp; },
    paint2FgaPg: (obj) => { return obj.paint2Fga / obj.gp; },
    paint2FgPct: (obj) => { return obj.paint2Fgm / obj.paint2Fga; }
}
```

There is a pattern, with similar functions being created for each zone `atr2`, `paint2`, etc. we have many other zones and many other metrics. For simplifying the code, we tried refactoring to:

```
let eqs2 = {}
const zones = ['atr2', 'paint2'];
zones.forEach(zone => {
    eqs2[`${zone}FgmPg`] = (obj) => obj[`${zone}Fgm`] / obj.gp;
    eqs2[`${zone}FgaPg`] = (obj) => obj[`${zone}Fga`] / obj.gp;
    eqs2[`${zone}FgPct`] = (obj) => obj[`${zone}Fgm`] / obj[`${zone}Fga`]
});
```

For how we use the `eqs` object, it really helps for the functions to be named. However, console.log() the output of these two objects in React shows the following:

[image]

Is there any way to create this object using the 2nd method with `eqs2`, while having the functions named in the same manner as they are in `eqs1`. Not sure if it is notable or not, but in the chrome dev tools console there are no names for the functions in either object?...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript  this will help assign a name for the functions. but still it will not be logged the same way in the console not sure why exactly https://codeshare.io/Adw408

Comment: This is closely related too. Not sure if it counts as "named" for your purposes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479046/is-there-any-non-eval-way-to-create-a-function-with-a-runtime-determined-name

Comment: @cmgchess yes this is working as we need it to!, even though it is not logged in the same way in the console as you mentioned. very interesting.