# var varName = function funcName() {}

Tags: javascript, function

What is the difference between

```
var a = function() {}
```

and

```
var a = function b() {}
```

The latter, b is undefined?

Comment: @iJay: no, it's not wrong

Comment: The latter will have a `name` property, `a.name === 'b'`

Comment: In the latter, b is defined only within the function but should be undefined outside it. The purpose is to allow anonymous functions to recurse. Older Mozilla or IE (don't remember) had a bug where b is not undefined outside the function - but the recursion thing still worked.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: not duplicate, I've read that topic before ask. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @ThịnhPhạm Did you read the answers too?

Comment: @Pumbaa80: that's about function expressions vs definitions, which is _slightly_ different than this question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I understand that the question is different. Dozens of variations of this have been asked (for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/), but they are all answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/27862

Answer (score 4):

The second one is a [named anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854141/naming-an-anonymous-function) - the name will appear in a stacktrace (otherwise in the stacktrace you''ll see just "anonymous function")

Comment: Technically its called a named function expression. It's used to implement recursive anonymous functions since you're no longer allowed to use arguments.callee in html5 strict mode

Comment: @Darhazer: Thanks! The latter will return "b" if I print out a.name.

Comment: @slebetman: maybe you're thinking of Javascript's strict mode, not html.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Yeah, brainfart on my part, I meant the new javascript strict mode as defined in ES5.

Answer (score 4):

The first is an anonymous function expression and the second a named function expression, both valid in Javascript.

For example, it can be used for recursion without `arguments.callee` (deprecated and not permitted in strict mode), because it refers to itself, no matter where.  The scope of the reference is local only to inside the function, that is it isn't accessible globally:

```
var a = function b(){
    return b;
 };
function c() {
    return c;
}
var d = function e() {
    return e();
};
d(); // maximum call stack size exceeded :P
var f = c;
c = null;
f(); // null
a(); // function
b();// undefined not a function
b; // not defined
a()(); // same function again
```

Comment: One more thing you forgot from your example: `a()()` which calls the returned "b" (which in this case is itself so it's just a bit silly, but informative nonetheless)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = function() {}
```

Function name can be omitted. In this case function name is omitted. These functions are called anonymous functions.

Read about javascript scope and anonymous function advantages and disadvantages for details.