# Javascript function returning global assigned to itself, then assigned to something else

Tags: javascript

```
var bar = function foo() {
  foo = 1;
  return foo;
};
bar(); // returns function foo()
```

Why is this happening? I expect this to return 1.

Comment: Isn't that a syntax error? Can you name an anonymous function like that?

Comment: Well, if it's a syntax error, why is my Firefox accepting that language?

Comment: @Thilo this is JS, a bunch of (possibly) bad things are technically legal. This is a legal thing to do. It doesn't really make much sense though... both `foo` and `bar` will reference the same function.

Comment: No, bar will represent what the function declaration returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar question that describes the same behavior...

[Function and variable with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057649/function-and-variable-with-the-same-name)

And a linked article that describes what is happening...

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to return 1, you need to write it like this:

```
var bar = function() {
  foo = 1;
  return foo;
};
```

[LVarayut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29001135/2319844) is actually right, you are writing over foo which is in the global namespace. This version declares a local variable foo.

```
var bar = function() {
  var foo = 1;
  return foo;
};
```

Comment: I know. But I'm motivated as to WHY this is happening.

Comment: @jetru a you are assigning a function **declaration** to bar. Not a function itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have defined foo variable twice, so if you want to return 1, you could change the name of your function to anything else:

```
var bar = function baz() {
  foo = 1;
  return foo;
};
bar(); // returns 1
```

Or you could define a local variable:

```
var bar = function foo() {
  var foo = 1;
  return foo;
};
bar(); // returns 1
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the answer of your question. The name of a named function expression becomes a local variable and can be only accessed inside the function expression. There is a distinction between the function name and the variable the function is assigned to. **The function name cannot be changed**, while the variable the function is assigned to can be reassigned.

[Read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: `var bar = function foo(){}`... Can you explain how this "named anonymous function" syntax works?

Comment: @Thilo See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854141/naming-an-anonymous-function.

Comment: @Thilo, yes, this named function expression is very useful when you have some errors in your function because the compiler could tell you the exact function caused the error.