# How to access a function object from within?

Tags: javascript, function

Suppose I want to register a single-use event listener on a button, I could write:

```
var someButton;
var once = function() {
  console.log("clicked");
  someButton.removeEventListener("click", once);
};
someButton.addEventListener("click", once);
```

What if I don't even want to give that function a name? Like:

```
var someButton;
someButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
  someButton.removeEventListener("click", /* what goes here? */);
});
```

Comment: Exactly! this is why (among other reasons) it is best to provide named functions as handlers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give it a name. You can use a named function expression though.

```
someButton.addEventListener("click", function foo () {
  console.log("clicked");
  someButton.removeEventListener("click", foo);
});
```

It will be scoped so it is only accessible from within the function.

---

Alternatively, use the new (very new, requires Chrome 55 or Firefox 50, no MSIE, Opera or stable Safari support at the time of writing) options syntax for addEventListener:

```
someButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("clicked");
}, { once: true });
```

Answer (score 4):

> What if I don't even want to give that function a name? Like:

Just give it a name anyway!

```
var someButton;
someButton.addEventListener("click", function once() {
  console.log("clicked");
  someButton.removeEventListener("click", once);
});
```

This has the added bonus that your stack trace will now show the function name.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854141/naming-an-anonymous-function

Answer (score 3):

You can give the function a name that isn't in scope anywhere except inside it:

```
var someButton;
someButton.addEventListener("click", function handler() {
  console.log("clicked");
  someButton.removeEventListener("click", handler);
});
```

That *doesn't* create a `handler` identifier binding in the scope where `someButton` is. (Historical note: IE8 and earlier had a bug where it did.)

If you really don't want to do that, and you don't mind using loose mode and using things that are deprecated, you could use `arguments.callee` instead:

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED AT ALL. WILL NOT WORK IN STRICT MODE.
var someButton;
someButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
  someButton.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee);
});
```